# Python class information from variable

Tags: python, class

In the following code:

```
class species:
    def __init__(self, continent):
        self.continent=continent

giraffe = species("africa")

animal = "giraffe"
```

EDIT: animal is a string

can i retrieve "africa" from var "animal"?

Comment: **animal.continent** is the reference you need.  Please look up these details in a tutorial on classes and objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: access class variables via instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313471/python-access-class-variables-via-instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Both `animal` and `giraffe` are *references* to the same underlying object. Very much like "Jala015" and "Jala Smith" and "mom" (or dad?) might all be references to the same person.

Similarly, if you *change* the `continent` of the object via one of the references, that change will be visible through the other reference, since they both point to the same place.

**Update**

Now you say that animal is not a reference to an object, but a string. There are a couple of ways to do that, all of them somewhat complex.

First, if `giraffe` is a global (as shown in your code, it is) then it will be in the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=globals#globals) dictionary. You can do this:

```
giraffe = species('Africa')
animal = "giraffe"

continent = globals()[animal].continent
```

If giraffe is not global, but rather a local variable in a function, that won't work. You might be able to get it with `locals()` but even that is iffy. In that case, and **in general,** you should probably put this stuff in your own dictionary for lookups:

```
Zoo = {}  # empty dictionary

giraffe = species('Africa')

Zoo['giraffe'] = giraffe

animal = "giraffe"

continent = Zoo[animal].continent
```

You can make this simpler by storing the species name in the `Animal` class, thus:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, where):
        self.name = name
        self.continent = where
```

Then you could put your objects into a deque, dict, list, set, tuple, or whatever other thing you like, and still match them by *brute force*:

```
Zoo = [ Animal('giraffe', 'Africa'), Animal('zebra', 'Africa'), Animal('Cheeto-Stained Ferret-Wearing Shitgibbon', 'North America') ]

pet = None

for animal in Zoo:
    if animal.name == 'giraffe':
        pet = animal
        break
```

Comment: i forgot: animal = "giraffe"

Comment: Well, that changes everything.

Comment: Updated with more examples.

Answer (score -1):

Access the attribute

animal.continent

Comment: i forgot: animal = "giraffe"