# some confusion with variables declared by python class

Tags: python, class

I have the class

```
>>> class Foo:
...     ls=[]
...
>>> f1=Foo()
>>> f2=Foo()
>>> f1.ls.append(1)
>>> f1.ls.append(2)
>>> print f1.ls
[1, 2]
>>> print f2.ls   
[1, 2]                #I expect its result is empty [], why
>>> f2.ls=[]
>>> print f1.ls       
[1, 2]
>>> print f2.ls
[]
           # If f1.ls and f2.ls refer to the same list, since i modify f2.ls,
           # the f1.ls is empty ,too. Does the statement 'f2.ls=[]' add new attribute
           # to f2. Where do f1.ls and f2.ls refer and how it happens
```

I want to use one class and declare many variables. If I hope all variables have different lists. Do I do like this

```
class Foo:
    pass
f1=Foo()
f2=oo()
f1.ls=[]
f2.ls=[]
do others
```

Are there some more simple and better methods.
Forgive my ignorant for python class. Thanks in advance

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701500/python-class-instance-variables-and-class-variables

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static class variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a variable directly inside a class gives a class-level variable. Thus, `ls` isn't unique to all instances, but is instead a property of the class `Foo`. It can still be accessed, however, through its instances, which is what you did.

```
class Foo:
    ls = []
```

So that:

```
>>> f1 = Foo()
>>> f2 = Foo()
>>> Foo.ls.append(1)
>>> Foo.ls
[1]
>>> f1.ls
[1]
>>> f2.ls
[1]
```

An instance level variable is unique to each instance, and can be defined in the `__init__` function, as such:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ls = []
```

In this way, class Foo has no attribute `ls`; rather, each instance constructed with `__init__` does:

```
>>> f1 = Foo()
>>> f2 = Foo()
>>> Foo.ls.append(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class Foo has no attribute 'ls'
>>> f1.ls.append(1)
>>> f1.ls
[1]
>>> f2.ls
[]
```

Comment: For the class-level list variable, does both f1.ls and f2.ls refer to the Foo.ls. If it is, when I change f2.ls=[], why does f2.ls remains to previous value

Comment: By saying `f2.ls = []`, you aren't modifying the original class-level `ls`; you're redefining `f2.ls` and overwriting its reference to `Foo.ls` to refer to a new, empty list.

Comment: If you wanted to modify the class-level `ls` from `f2`, you could use `f2.ls[:] = []`

Answer (score 3):

Class-level assignments create class variables. To create instance variables, do so in the constructor:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.ls = []
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
class Foo:
    ls=[]
```

`ls` is defined as a class variable and all the objects which you create will will have a variable with the same name and that variable will point to the current value in the class's `ls` value.

When you say

```
f1.ls.append(1)
```

You are actually mutating the original object. That's why the change is reflected in `f2` as well (since they both are referring to the same object). But when you say

```
f2.ls = []
```

You are actually creating a variable on the `f2` object, which refers to an empty list object. Now, the `ls` object is different from `f1`'s ls. You can confirm this with this statement

```
print f1.ls is f2.ls    # Will print False
print f1.ls is Foo.ls   # Will print True
```

If you actually wanted to get a new object whenever you created an object. You have to create an instance variable, like this

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ls = []

f1, f2 = Foo(), Foo()
print f1.ls is f2.ls    # Will print False
```

Now you are binding `ls` to the current instance of the class and making it point to an empty list. So, this will be different for each instance.

Comment: thanks for your comments. Can I understand the class-variables and instance-variables like this, class-variable likes static variables in C++ and instance-variables like normal member variables in C++. Excuse my another question, does the def (function) in python class have class-function and instance-function

Comment: @user2256235 You can roughly think of them as static variables. And yes Python has class functions and instance functions as well :) You can read more about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38238/1903116)

Answer (score 0):

ls is a static variable as you defined. you self.ls in the **init** so you can have different ls in the memory.