# Python Variable empty i don't know why

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, instance

guys i have a problem with my variable.

When i instance my class my variable dossierProd and dossierModif is not empty but when i want use another function she is empty.

```
    import glob
    class OBDI:

dossierProd = ""
dossierModif = ""
listeFichierProd = []
listeFichierModif = []

def __init__(self, dossierP, dossierM):
    dossierProd = dossierM
    dossierModif = dossierM

def recupListeFichier(self):
    HERE MY VARIaBLE dossierProd & dossierModif  as empty
    for fichier in glob.glob(str(self.dossierProd) + '*.csv'):
        self.listeFichierProd.append(fichier.replace("\\", "/"))

    for fichier in glob.glob(str(self.dossierModif) + '*.csv'):
        self.listeFichierModif.append(fichier.replace("\\", "/"))



    if len(self.listeFichierProd) != len(self.listeFichierModif):
       print "toto
```

Have you got an idea why my variable is empty ?

Thx to your response.
Sorry for my bad english ;)

---

Oh thanks, this error is so stupid.
I'm to be accustomed to java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized `dossierP` and `dossierM` instance variables in `__init__()`:

```
def __init__(self, dossierP, dossierM):
    self.dossierProd = dossierM
    self.dossierModif = dossierM
```

Watch `self.` here.

Also, since  it appears that `dossierProd` and `dossierModif` variables make sense only for when you have an instance of a `OBDI` class, remove `dossierProd = ""` and `dossierModif = ""` lines.

Also, you probably don't want to share `listeFichierProd` and `listeFichierModif` lists between `OBDI` class instances - initialize lists in `__init__()`:

```
def __init__(self, dossierP, dossierM):
    self.dossierProd = dossierM
    self.dossierModif = dossierM
    self.listeFichierProd = []
    self.listeFichierModif = []
```

and remove `listeFichierProd = []` and `listeFichierModif = []` lines.

Make sure you understand what is discussed in the following threads:

- [Instance variables vs. class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python)
- [python class instance variables and class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701500/python-class-instance-variables-and-class-variables?rq=1)

Hope that helps.