# Strange behaviour in python

Tags: python, class, oop

Here is a strange behaviour I observed with `list` objects in `Python` classes.

```
class Test:
    val = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.val.append(42)

a = Test()
b = Test()
print b.val
```

The output of above program is `[42,42]` rather than the expected `[42]`.

```
class Test:
    val = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.val+=5

a = Test()
b = Test()
print b.val
```

In this case the output is `5` as expected.

Following the rule above program showed, this program should have given output `10`. Or vice-versa, the above output should have been only `[42]`.

If multiple objects of the same type are instantiated, how are the `list` type objects accessible in different objects? This completely defies my `OOP` concepts.

Comment: Yoy may find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8701644/2679935

Comment: You are using class attributes instead of instance attributes. Class attributes are shared amongst all instances of a class. And since you create two instances `a` and `b`, `__init__` gets called twice, appending to the list twice.

Comment: @Lukas that doesn't explain why in the second example, `val` isn't incremented twice.

Comment: lists  are  mutable ints are not

Comment: @TomFenech because in the second example he doesn't modify `self.val` (since it's immutable), he re-assigns is as an instance attribute every time.