# different behavior of strings and numbers in python when dealing with class and object variables

Tags: python, class, variables, object

I found one issue and not able to understand the reason of difference:

code1:

```
class Test:
    var=2
    def __init__(self):
        self.var=self.var+1

p=Test()
print "p.var:",p.var
q=Test()
print "q.var:",q.var
```

output 1:

```
p.var:3
q.var:3
```

Why not the output is(According to concept used to explain code2)

```
p.var:3
q.var:4
```

Code2:

```
class Test:
    var=[]
    def __init__(self):
        self.var.append("fool")

p=Test()
print "p.var:",p.var
q=Test()
print "q.var:",q.var
```

output2:

```
p.var: ['fool']
q.var: ['fool', 'fool']
```

i read the article on code2 in Stack Exchange:
[python class instance variables and class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701500/python-class-instance-variables-and-class-variables)

but not able to link code1 with the following concept.Please help

Comment: This has nothing to do with "strings and numbers". In the first piece of code you have an integer, which you replace; in the second, you have a list, on which you call `append`. These are fundamentally different operations, so it shouldn't surprise you that they have different effects, surely?

Comment: I think he's curious as to why `q.var` is 3 and not 4.

Comment: thanks Daniel,i have one confusion, why the output is not 3 and 4 in first case, or the class variable is not updated in first case but it is in the second one?

Comment: @wilbur that is what i need to know..thank u..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here is that lists are mutable objects; integers are immutable.
When code1 increments self.var, it *must* return a new object, that being 3.  On the second call,w e start over with 2, producing another 3 for object **q**.

In code2, **var** is still a class object (only one for the class, not one per object).  When we create **p**, we append "fool" to the empty list.  When we later create **q** we append a second "fool".  Print them both:

```
p=Test2()
print "p.var1:",p.var
q=Test2()
print "q.var2:",q.var
print "p.var2:",p.var
```

output:

```
p.var1: ['fool']
q.var2: ['fool', 'fool']
p.var2: ['fool', 'fool']
```

Does that clarify things?

Comment: The difference isn't just about whether the data types are mutable. If the list example had done `self.var = self.var + ['fool']`, it would have behaved the same as the first example. Also, a proper explanation of what's going on should really cover how the first example creates instance attributes that hide the class attribute.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112 for your reply, can u please explain little more?