# Accessing variable within def clean() from def __init__()

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've established a variable inside my def **init** function inside my form that I want to be able to access within def clean() in that same form.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                         
        super(UserOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        car = 'BMW'

def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = super(UserOrderForm, self).clean()
       print(car)
```

When I print car, I'm told that

```
name 'car' is not defined
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you declare instance attributes using `self`, you must change your code to

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                         
        super(UserOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.car = 'BMW'

def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = super(UserOrderForm, self).clean()
       print(self.car)
```

In your original code, the variable `car` does exists only inside the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 0):

i think you make the car a member variables, then set it in the init method with self.car = "bmw".

then when you want to see the value in clean, you call self.clean

[python class instance variables and class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701500/python-class-instance-variables-and-class-variables)

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you're trying to do, but your form should declare a model to get a queryset to work with.

```
class UserOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Cars
        fields = ['manufacturer', 'model_number', 'etc']
        widgets = {'manufacturer': forms.Select}
```

Your users will provide the input, for example selecting BMW from a select field.

Check out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/