# Same class variables in different instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have two class instances as follows

```
class Foo: 
    def __init__(self, a = 5): 
        self.a = a
f1 = Foo()
f2 = Foo()
```

Now when I compare the two, `f1 is f2` evaluates to `False` obviously. However, `f1.a is f2.a` is `True`. This is a big problem when `a` is a list like object. How does this happen and how do I get around this (without hardcoding `a`'s value inside `__init__`)?

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701500/python-class-instance-variables-and-class-variables) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances) questions. But they do not answer how I am getting this behavior with no class variable `a`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers

Comment: @ThierryLathuille in my use case it is `a=np.zeros(3)` in the constructor arguments. `np.zeros(3) is np.zeros(3)` is `False`. So still does not explain the behavior.

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ function defaults are only evaluated once, so yes, you have to move the default inside `__init__` rather than in the signature. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: In both cases f1.a and f2.a value is 5. So the result should be true. If you change it or if you initialize it with another value it won't be true.

Comment: "Never use `is` to compare numbers.".I saw it in the Thierry's link.

Comment: @AlexHall Got it. That what I was trying to figure out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function defaults get evaluated once. To see this in action, use `random`.

```
In [163]: class Foo:  
 ...:     def __init__(self, a =random.random()):  
 ...:         self.a = a 
 ...: f1 = Foo() 
 ...: f2 = Foo()                                                                                 

In [164]:                                                                                            

In [164]: f1.a                                                                                       
Out[164]: 0.6880171149267156

In [165]: f2.a                                                                                       
Out[165]: 0.6880171149267156
```

Comment: A better proof would be to examine the value of `Foo.__init__.__defaults__`, as it's not *impossible* for `random.random()` to return the same value twice in a row :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy) to deep copy object which contains objects...

```
import copy

class Foo: 
    def __init__(self, a=5): 
        self.a = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Of course, for `int` deepcopy is useless. It is useful for `list`, `dict`, etc.