# How do I pass the same variable(iterable) between instances of different classes(that inherits from the same parent)

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, class-variables

I want to pass a variable(iterable )between instances of different classes. I have a structure similar with the one below.

Each class has its own module(so no globals) and needs to work in python 3 and 2.

```
class O:
    pass


class A(O):
    pass


class B(O):

    def __init__(self, cache):
        self.cache = cache


class B1(B):

    def p(self):
        self.cache.add_to_cache("32", "something something")


class B2(B):

    def p(self):
        self.cache.get_from_cache("52",  "something else")
```

For `B` and its sub-classes I want to create a cache. All instances of this classes(B, B1, B2) to use the same cache.

To keep it simple, let's say that the cache is just a dict.

```
c = {}

a = A(c)
b1 = B() - needs c
b1.p()
b2 = C() - needs c
b2.p()

print(cache)
```

Off course the example above, is wrong because the cache is different for each instance.

The chache should be :

```
{
"32", "something something"
"52":  "something else"
}
```

Comment: If you want to share the data over different instances you should make `cache` a class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to this is using CacheService as an injectable Singleton service, which I consider a better practice.
[Read this first for a code/syntax solution to your direct question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67583548/913098), or continue reading for a solution with better design.

```
class O(object):
    pass

class CacheService(object):
    __instances = {}

    @staticmethod
    def getinstance(owner_id):
        if owner_id not in CacheService.__instances:
            CacheService.__instances[owner_id] = CacheService(owner_id)
        return CacheService.__instances[owner_id]

    def __init__(self, owner_id):
        self._owner_id = owner_id
        self._owner_query = CacheService.__name__ + self._owner_id
        self._cache = {}

    def put_in_cache(self, key, value):
        self._cache[self._owner_query + str(key)] = value

    def get_from_cache(self, key):
        return self._cache.get(self._owner_query + str(key), "the_default")


class B(O):
    def __init__(self):
        self._cache = CacheService.getinstance(B.__name__)

class B1(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B1, self).__init__()

    def p(self):
        val1 = self._cache.get_from_cache("a")
        print(val1)


class B2(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B2, self).__init__()

    def p(self):
        self._cache.put_in_cache("a", 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b1 = B1()
    b2 = B2()

    b2.p()
    b1.p()
```

out:

> 2

---

This still uses a class variable, but hides it from your "everyday code", and moves it to the "infrastructure level".
I see this as cleaner, as now your class hierarchy shouldn't handle its own global variables.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer the programming question, Use [class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701500/python-class-instance-variables-and-class-variables).

As a side note, it would be much better to use some kind of "CacheService" and inject that to the constructor, rather than use inheritance and class variables.
For this, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67583799/913098).

---

Code for using class variables follows:

```
class O(object):
    pass

class B(O):
    __cache = {}  # use your cache class if you want, I am using dict just for show
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def _get_from_cache(self, key):
        return self._cache.get(key, "default1")

    def _put_in_cache(self, key, value):
        self._cache[key] = value


class B1(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B1, self).__init__()

    def p(self):
        val1 = self._get_from_cache("a")
        print(val1)


class B2(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B2, self).__init__()

    def p(self):
        self._put_in_cache("a", 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b1 = B1()
    b2 = B2()

    b2.p()
    b1.p()
```

out:

> 2

---

Notice `_get_from_cache` and `_put_in_cache` are methods, but they can be `@staticmethod`s, as they only ever access class variables, and their `self` isn't "really" ever being used. `__cache` could theoretically be accessed directly by children, but the `_get_from_cache` and `_put_in_cache` makes `__cache` private, and gives a protected API to it.