# Why does accessing `self.BASE_DIR` lead to "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'BASE_DIR'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Inside a python class the `with open` line gets:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "c:\Users\anonymous\Desktop\checker.py", line 54, in <module>
    print(main.check("fubk"))   
File "c:\Users\anonymous\Desktop\checker.py", line 13, in check
    with open(f"{self.BASE_DIR}\\wordlist.txt", "r") as words: 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'BASE_DIR'
```

```
class main:
    BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    def __init__(self, string, similarity: float = 0.76, BASE_DIR =  BASE_DIR):
        self.string = string
        self.similarity = similarity
        self.BASE_DIR = BASE_DIR
        print(self.DATADIR)

    def check(self):
        with open(f"{self.BASE_DIR}\\wordlist.txt", "r") as words:
            badwords = words.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include the other parts of the error message, specifically the part that shows the exact line that is raising the error. Also, include how you are using and instantiating this `main` class.

Comment: I suggest *not* using the same name `BASE_DIR` for both the class variable and the instance variable, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Edited, but `with open`  should accept string right?

Comment: Yes, it should. But it seems you are using the class incorrectly. You are calling the method `main.check("fubk")` but your `check` method is not accepting any arguments. And you should call `check` on an *instance* of `main`, not on `main` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using classes incorrectly. I recommend going through the tutorials on classes (again, even if you already have), such as this one from the Python docs: [A First Look at Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

#### How to Fix

Basically, you are making 2 mistakes:

1. Calling `check` on the `main` class directly, not on an *instance* of `main`
2. Defining `check` without the correct parameters, but still passing `"fubk"` when calling it

1st, change `check` to be a proper instance method:

```py
def check(self, word):
    print(word)
    with open(f"{self.BASE_DIR}\\wordlist.txt", "r") as words:
        badwords = words.read().splitlines()
    if word in badwords:
        ...
```

An instance method's 1st parameter should be the instance object itself (`self`). So if you want to pass some argument to your function, you need to add it to your function definition (ex. `word`).

2nd, you need to *instantiate* an object of `main`. Then call `check` on it.

```py
main_obj = main("string", similarity=0.5)
main_obj.check("fubk")
```

Here, the `check` method will receive the instance object as `self` (so it has access to all the `self.string`, `self.BASE_DIR`, etc. instance attributes) and the input `"fubk"` as `word`. (I don't know what the `string` parameter is for).

#### What did the original error mean?

Your original error:

```
    print(main.check("fubk"))   
File "c:\Users\anonymous\Desktop\checker.py", line 13, in check
    with open(f"{self.BASE_DIR}\\wordlist.txt", "r") as words:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'BASE_DIR'
```

is because `check` received `"fubk"` as `self` when it was called. You can see it if you printed out `self`.

```
    def check(self):
        print(self)
        ...

main.check("fubk")
```

which would print out `fubk`. Your original code was trying to do:

```py
# {self.BASE_DIR}
"fubk".BASE_DIR
```

which leads to `"'str' object has no attribute 'BASE_DIR'"`.

Again, this error is avoidable if you instantiate your objects and define your instance methods properly. In Python, `self` has a "special" meaning: see [What is the purpose of the word 'self'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21366809/2745495).

In addition, to avoid confusion, don't give your *class* variables and your *instance* variables the same name. It can lead to some confusing behavior that you'll have to debug later (example: [python class instance variables and class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8701500/2745495)).

```
class main:
    # class variable
    DEFAULT_BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    # rename BASE_DIR function parameter
    def __init__(self, string, similarity: float = 0.76, custom_base_dir = None):
        ...
        # use parameter if provided or class default 
        self.BASE_DIR = custom_base_dir or DEFAULT_BASE_DIR

    def check(self):
        with open(f"{self.BASE_DIR}\\wordlist.txt", "r") as words:
            badwords = words.read().splitlines()
```