# Python class variable (immutable) not properly updating

Tags: python

Here is a code snippet:

```
 class h:
     v = 0
     def __init__(self):
             print(self.v)
     def add(self):
             self.v += 1
     def show(self):
             print(self.v)

 h.v
0
 a = h()
0
 a.add()
 a.show()
1
 h.v
0
```

In other words, when the instance of `h` updates the class variable, they no longer share it. Is this because the type of `int` is immutable? How can you share something like an `int` without the usage of a global?

Edit for clarity: `h.v` did not get updated with `a.add()`. I had expected it to.

Comment: You’d see the same thing if you *did* the same thing to a mutable value (reassigned an attribute containing it). Not sure what you’re asking re: sharing. Are you looking for `type(self).v`?

Comment: Why use `self.v += 1`? You can use `h.v += 1` and then `print(h.v)` in `show()` method.

Comment: `self.v += 1` is essentially `self.v = self.v + 1`. The `self.v` on the right hand side is _read_ from the class, because it doesn't exist on the instance, but is then _assigned_ to the instance `self`. If you want to modify a *class attribute*, you need to explicitly refer to the class object, not the instance.

Comment: BTW, that's _not_ how your code snippet should behave!? `add.show()` should print `1`, but `h.v` should print `0`.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant sorry @deceze. Thanks for the explanation. You answered exactly my question and I would accept that as answer. Misleadingly, I had thought that you could alter "class variables" via `self.[variable-name]` as I thought it behaves like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701500/python-class-instance-variables-and-class-variables)

Comment: If you're *mutating* an object, sure, that works. But as you said, ints are immutable and can only be reassigned.

Comment: I think the question is suitably different to be re-opened @deceze. It is on the subject of the mutation causing this

Comment: There are enough dupes of this. I added another one.

Comment: What is your question exactly? (I mean if it hasn't been answered already.) What output do you expect or want?

Comment: Note, `self.v += 1` *shadows* the class variable with an instance variable, because you are *assigning* to the instance. This will always work that way regardless if the types involved (although, you may end up shadowing your class variable with an instance variable that is referring to the same object)

Comment: It was answered by deceze @Code-Apprentice. I'll edit the question anyway for more clarity, although it is closed at this point.