# After overriding __new__ method in a class new object creation doesn't work as it's supposed to

Tags: python, django

I have a weird issue I can't get my head around. I'm trying to use https://github.com/Climbcare/unleashed to push some orders to Unleashed API. It has the following Python generator class that's inherited by another class:

```
class MetaResource(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        """
        Looks for attributes whith a `__resourcefield__`  attribute and adds them to  `        __resourcefields__`.
        Replace the attribute with a property so its value can be directly accessed.
        """

        dct['__resourcefields__'] = {}
        dct['__embeddedresources__'] = {}

        for attr_name, attr in dct.iteritems():
            if hasattr(attr, '__resourcefield__') and attr.__resourcefield__:
                dct['__resourcefields__'][attr_name] = attr
                attr.__fieldname__ = attr_name
                attr.__parentresource__ = name
            elif hasattr(attr, '__metaclass__') and attr.__metaclass__ == mcs:
                dct['__embeddedresources__'][attr_name] = attr

        return super(MetaResource, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        cls.guess_endpoint()
        cls.convert_fields()
        cls.convert_embedded_resources()
        super(MetaResource, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
```

That class is extended by this class:

```
class UnleashedResource(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaResource

    # Override if necessary
    __endpoint__ = None

    # Created by metaclass
    __resourcefields__ = {}
    __embeddedresources__ = {}

    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps(
            self.to_dict(),
            sort_keys=True,
            indent=4,
            separators=(',', ': ')
        )

    def from_dict(self, dict_val):
        """
        Set all the resource's field values from a dictionary.
        """
        if not dict_val:
            return

        for field, value in dict_val.iteritems():
            if hasattr(self, field):
                setattr(self, field, value)
```

And then there's a class that extends UnleashedResource class:

```
class Product(UnleashedResource):
    __endpoint__ = 'Products'

    AverageLandPrice = fields.FieldNullableDecimal()
    Barcode = fields.FieldString()
    BinLocation = fields.FieldString()
    CanAutoAssemble = fields.FieldBoolean()
    ...
```

As you can se MetaResource is a **metaclass** for UnleashedResource class.

What's strange is that when you create mulitple instance of the Product() class, all those instance are the same, even though they have different memory ids. For example:

```
p1 = Product()
p2 = Product()
```

Any change to p1 will also exist in p2. And printing Product() will also give me the same thing.

I read up on **metaclass** and I'm still not getting anywhere.

Check this out:

```
>>> from unleashed.resources.product import Product
>>> p1 = Product()
>>> type(p1)
<class 'unleashed.resources.product.Product'>
>>> p1.Barcode = 12345
>>> p2 = Product()
>>> p2.Barcode
12345
>>> id(p1)
4414711632
>>> id(p2)
4414356560
>>> Product().Barcode
12345
>>> id(Product())
4414711568
>>> type(Product())
<class 'unleashed.resources.product.Product'>
>>>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Complexity always leads to trouble. There is probably a simpler, clearer, more straightforward way of doing this.

Comment: The attributes the metaclass creates are class attributes and are shared among all instances.  See gazillions of previous questions about this, e.g., [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860447/why-does-python-seem-to-treat-instance-variables-as-shared-between-objects).  Why are you doing this in a metaclass instead of just using a regular class and putting that data in instance attributes on each instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a tricky one, but I think I have figured out what is going on here.  The metaclass is taking all of the class attributes that are "fields" and converting them to properties.

Now normally when you assign to an attribute on an instance it will always be an instance attribute, even if there is also a class attribute with the same name.  However if your class attribute is a property with a setter defined, then assigning to that attribute (whether it is from the class or an instance) will call the setter function.  The end result here is that assigning to a class property through an instance will result in that property being changed for all instances.

The easiest way to think of this is that assigning to a property isn't really an assignment, it is a mutation.  It shouldn't be too surprising that in the following code `f1.foo` and `f2.foo` are the same object and modification to one will modify the other:

```
class Foo(object):
    test = []

f1 = Foo()
f2 = Foo()
f1.test.append(1)  # f1.test is actually Foo.test, so class attribute changes
print f2.test      # f2.test is also Foo.test, so this prints [1]
```

The same principle applies to properties and descriptors, for example:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self.val = val

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        self.val = val

class Foo(object):
    test = Test()

f1 = Foo()
f2 = Foo()
f1.test = 'abc'  # calls Foo.test.__set__
print f2.test    # prints 'abc', because Foo.test was modified above
```

Comment: I believe `Product` is supposed to be an ORM-style class, that creates instance variables of the same names as the class variables. Perhaps the metaclass is intended to accomplish this, but it is not working as intended?

Comment: `f2.class_attr` is abc, try it. Python has weird behaviour around class/instance attributes depending on whether mutable/immutable types are used. You assigned a string, an immutable, to `class_attr` so it behaves more like an instance attribute.

Comment: Oops, yeah my previous answer was wrong.  Did some more investigation and it looks like the metaclass is turning the fields into properties, which explains this behavior.  My edited answer should now explain what is going on.

Comment: @jpmc26 - That's correct. It's an attempt at that and works beautifully if you can get away with a single instance.