# Difference between Class Members and Instance Members in Django and "Ordinary" Python?

Tags: python, django, class, definition

Beginner question here! Some time ago, I asked this question: 
[Parse CSV records into a list of Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817596/parse-csv-records-into-a-list-of-classes), which was also answered more technically here: [How do I avoid having class data shared among instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-do-i-avoid-having-python-class-data-shared-among-instances)

I learned that, in Python classes, variables that will be defined on a per-object basis need to be declared in the `__init__(self)` function.

So for:

```
class ClassOne:
    def __init__(self, datetime):
        self.datetime = datetime
    v = []
```

the variable v will hold the **same data for all instances** of `ClassOne`, whereas for:

```
class ClassTwo:
    def __init__(self, datetime):
        self.datetime = datetime
        self.v = []
```

variable v holds **individual data for each instance** of `ClassTwo`.

However, in Django (which I'm learning now), I see the "normal" (more C++ like) behavior again for the variables:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

Here, the variable `title` holds **individual data for each instance** of `Post`, despite not being defined in the `__init__` function.

My basic question is **Why** or **How** does `title` pertain to **individual class objects** instead of being common to **every class object**, as `v` in `ClassOne` is above?

If I'm understanding this right, this means that Django classes are interpreted differently than normal Python classes?  However, that conclusion doesn't make sense...

I hope that someone can help me understand this.  It was my assumption previously that  python code (say, a data analysis or a scientific model) could be built into a web-based service by using it's classes and routines in a Django app.  If the implementation of the two different classes is different, then this would be quite difficult!

This may have been answered elsewhere.  I'm not well versed in Django jango, so don't know what to search for.

Comment: You probably meant to set `self.v = []` in `ClassTwo.__init__`; just `v` is a function local.

Comment: You're right on that, I fixed it.  I also clarified the question a little: why is `title` treated differently than `v`?

Comment: What makes you think it is treated differently? It is no different from setting any other attribute on the class; you can refer directly to those attributes **on the class**. `Post.title` now exists. You can enumerate all attributes on the `Post` class and the list will include `title`. That is the *point*.

Comment: And the `title` attribute **is** shared among instances as well, but the instances have a `title` attribute **as well**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `title` attribute is *not data*. It holds a model description only; an object *describing* what type of information the `title` field should hold.

As such it is part of the class definition; individual instances of the `Post` class will have a `title` attribute that conforms to the constraints set in the `models.CharField()` instance on the class.

You need to build such a model to describe to Django how to build form fields and how to build a SQL table for the `Post` instances; both are concepts that need to have more type information than what Python normally itself needs.

Individual instances of `Post` are given a `title` attribute **as well**. That attribute then masks the class attribute:

```
p = Post(title='Some title')
print p.title  # prints 'Some title'
```

Python looks at the instance directly first; if it does *not* have a `title` attribute, lookup would then move to the class object. But that's not needed here, the `Post.title` attribute is not found as the instance has a `title` attribute itself.

In Python itself, there is no absolute distinction between 'data' and methods, by the way. *Everything* in Python is an object, including classes and methods. As such, looking up an attribute on an instance can find an object there too, **including methods**. If an attribute lookup there fails, then Python will look for the attribute on the class and base classes, and if that fails, lookup falls back to the metaclass even.

This is where mutable attributes come in; looking up `ClassOne().v` fails on the instance, but succeeds on the class. Manipulating that list then alters `ClassOne.v` the class attribute, and looking up `v` on **other** instances once again will find the class attribute. This is how class attributes are shared, just like the methods on the class.

Comment: So is it right to understand that the `title` attribute is a class instance _inside_ the `Post` class?  Similar to, say, `Toppings` (a class with variables such as `type`, `amount`, etc.), which is used in the `Pizza` class?  Per my understanding, `Toppings` (and `title`, for that matter) would still need to be declared inside the `__init__` function, no?

Comment: No, you don't **have** to. You can use class attributes to *deliberately* share data, or to provide defaults. Once you set an attribute on the instance (`self.v = []` is setting such an attribute), the attribute on the class with the same name is masked. So you can set defaults on the class, and override specific attributes on instances.

Comment: I'm still not clear on why `title` is _not_ a class attribute?

Comment: @SwiftArrow: It is **both** a class attribute and an instance attribute. There are two separate attributes, and Python finds one during lookup.

Answer (score 4):

Django does not change the rules of the language. It does however use the language creatively. Just like `class ClassTwo(...): v = []` creates *one* list and stores it in the class, `class Post(...): title = something` creates one `something` and stores it in the class. In this case, said *something* is *not* a char field value like `"foo"`, it's an object which represents the *concept* of a char field with a max_length of 255.

Django gathers these objects representing database types, and creates (among many other things) an `__init__` method that gives `Post` *instances* an attribute of the same name (which *does* contain an actual string value). The implementation of this is quite advanced, but firmly within the rules of the Python language - you and I can create our own Python libraries doing something similar. Anyway, since instance attributes shadow class attributes, you never notice that `Post.title` exists only once and isn't actually a title string. `a_post_object.title` always gives you the instance attribute.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have made things a little clearer... So if I understand you correctly, Django's `models` process their inheriting classes and auto-create an `__init__` function, putting the actual data containers in it, for each class?  

Is it safe to say that if I wanted to make a class attribute, I could add a simple data variable in the django class definition?

Comment: @SwiftArrow: The base class provides the `__init__` method for you. There is no need to generate it. You can look at the [model base class on GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L365) if you so desire.

Answer (score 4):

As a slightly more general explanation of the relationship between class and instance variables, consider the following example that is unrelated to django models:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     x = 2
...     y = 1
...
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.x = 3
... 
>>> A.x
2
>>> instance = A()
>>> instance.x 
3
>>> instance.y
1
>>> instance.y = 4
>>> instance.y
4
>>> A.y
1
```

There are 2 things that I think are worth noting here.  Firstly, a separate class and instance variable of the same name can exist.  The class variable is only accessible directly from an instance if there is no instance variable of the same name.  This is how the django models work, the class variables are fields (which are descriptions of the instance variables), the instance variables are the values for the specific instances.  Using the same name for class and instance variables can be confusing, and isn't something to be done lightly. In the case of django models I think it works really well, but still can cause some headaches (I had similar questions when I first used django).

The second thing to note is that you can assign variables to an instance anywhere, it doesn't have to be in the `__init__` function or even in a method of the instance's class, it can be anywhere. That is not to say that making a point of defining all instance variables in the `__init__` function is a bad idea. In many cases it is a good idea.

Comment: why A.x become == [1] if say A.x = [], then instance.x.append(1) ??

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old thread. I happen to get the same question while I'm just new to Django.
Class of 'title' is models.CharField, which seems a python descriptor. According to the Descriptor definition, 'title' is a class variable. p.title = 'xxx', there is no instance 'title'. The above statement calls the class variable title to create a hidden title for the instance. print(p.title) will just call the class variable title to return the invisible title of instance.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html
Python cookbook chapter 8.6 also talks about the Descriptor.

Hope I'm correct and could help.