# How to use multiple return values functions in this particular way?

Tags: python, django

I have a function that returns two values:

```
def dbfunc:
  # ...
  return var1, var2
```

I have this class:

```
class MyClass:
  foo = ...
  bar = ...
```

I'd like to assign the result of dbfunc() to the MyClass instance I'm trying to create.
I'd tried this:

```
my_object = MyClass(dbfunc()) # does not work because the return type is a tuple
```

I could do this:

```
res = dbfunc()
my_object = MyClass(foo=res[0], bar=res[1])
```

but I'm actually trying to do this in a middle of a comprehensive list so I can not make these kind of "pre-affectations". I have to do it in one time.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
my_object = MyClass(*dbfunc())
```

Put a `*` before the last argument to a function, and Python will iterate over that argument and pass the elements to the function as separate positional arguments. You can use `**` with a dict for keyword arguments.

Also, it looks like you may have a bug regarding class vs. instance attributes. See "[How do I avoid having Python class data shared among instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-do-i-avoid-having-python-class-data-shared-among-instances)". It might or might not be fine, depending on the parts of `MyClass` you stripped out.

Answer (score 0):

You can define more simply your function and your class I think as shown below.

```
def dbfunc:
    # ...
    return var1, var2

class MyClass:
    def __init__(foo, bar):
        self.foo = name
        self.bar = bar

[var1, var2] = dbfunc()
my_object = MyClass(var1, var2)
```