# Python object with a list into attributes. List is empty when the object is passed by parameters

Tags: python, list, parameters, encapsulation

My class `gcb_ip` has those attributes:

```
class gcb_ip:
    ip = None
    country_code = None
    score = None
    asn = None
    records = list()
```

1) I fill up the records list with a specific method.

2) I can see the records and the rest of my attributes inside the object if I check it my main code.

3) I CAN'T see the records but the rest of my attributes inside the object if I check it into another class method passed by parameters.

I come from C++ and I guess that this is a copy/reference parameter passing issue. ¿What's going on?

Comment: Can you write an example of *non working code*?

Comment: What do you mean by "passed by parameters"? Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-do-i-avoid-having-python-class-data-shared-among-instances

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your `init` function properly defined, and have those parameters set? For example

```
class gcb_ip(object):
    def __init__(self, IP, country_code, score, asn):
        self.IP = IP
        self.country_code = country_code
        self.score = score
        self.asn = asn
        self.records = list()
```

This is the equivalent of setting up your explicit constructor in C++, and initializing your member variables.

Then you can reference the parameters of that object as you would expect, for example

```
myIP = someGcbObject.IP
```

Comment: Yes, I've been defined the constructor, and the class works 100% right. It's just that when I pass a class instance through parameter into another class method the 'records' list looks empty, but outside the method is not.