# python object persisting list accidentally between requests

Tags: python, oop, persistence, bottle

Reproduce with bottle app below.

I have a class with a list property. I create a new instance of this class on each request and append one element to the class' list property. Then, I print the length of the list back to the user.

Why does the count grow when visiting the page multiple times? If I set the property to an empty list in the class' init method everything is ok.

I'm running the app with gunicorn with a gevent worker proxied behind nginx

```
import bottle


class MyClass:
    my_list = []

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def add_to_list(self, var):
        self.my_list.append(var)


app = bottle.app()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    var = 'test'
    my_class = MyClass()
    my_class.add_to_list(var)
    return str(len(my_class.my_list))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="localhost", port=80)
```

Comment: You made it a class attribute, not an instance attribute.

Comment: sounds good to me; thanks, if someone adds an answer I'll accept or can close for the mentioned duplicate above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class attributes are shared among all instances of a class. What you're looking for is an instance attribute:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_list = []

    def add_to_list(self, var):
        self.my_list.append(var)
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-do-i-avoid-having-python-class-data-shared-among-instances) question for more information.