# how to implement iterator behavior in self.dict

Tags: python, iterator

I have a container object like this:

```
class myclass():
    self.data = dict()
    self.otherattribute = 0 ## anything
```

how to write `__iter__` and `__next__` to implement:

```
for i in myclass:
```

equal to:

```
for i in myclass.data:
```

Comment: You'll find that all your `myclass` instances seem to share the same `data` dict. Here's why and how to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-do-i-avoid-having-python-class-data-shared-among-instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just have `__iter__` return an iterator:

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__:
        self.data = {}

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)
```

With that, I can do this:

```
c = myclass()
c.data['key1'] = 'val1'
c.data['key2'] = 'val2'

for k in c:
    print k
```

Which gets me:

```
key2
key1
```