# Share global data in Python

Tags: python, list, class

I am building a project that requires the data to be shared globally. I built a class GlobalDataBase to handle these data, which is like the way in [How do I avoid having class data shared among instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-do-i-avoid-having-python-class-data-shared-among-instances) and https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html . However, I found something a little bit weird to me. My code is as follows:

```
class GlobalDataBase:

    a = []

    def copy_to_a(self, value):
        self.a = value  

    def assign_to_a(self, value):
        for idx in range(0, len(value)):
            self.a.append(value[idx])

def test_copy():

    gb1 = GlobalDataBase()
    gb1.copy_to_a([1,2])
    print gb1.a

    gb2 = GlobalDataBase()
    print gb2.a


def test_assign():

    gb1 = GlobalDataBase()
    gb1.assign_to_a([1,2])
    print gb1.a

    gb2 = GlobalDataBase()
    print gb2.a
```

The output of `test_copy` is

```
[1,2]

[]
```

The output of `test_assign` is

```
[1,2]

[1,2]
```

The result of the second method is what I was expecting. But I could not understand why the first method doesn't work. Could anyone explain the difference between these two methods?

Comment: About your `assign_to_a` method: more pythonic would be to write `for element in value: self.a.append(element)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is assigned with a list on `GlobalDataBase`'s declaration. Each instance of `GlobalDataBase` starts out with a *reference* to that same list, let's term it the "original" list.

When you do `self.a = value` in your first example, you replace, for that instance or "self", the reference to the original list with a reference to `value`, the list you assigned. Any new instance created will still reference the *original* list, and that's why `gb2` prints out an empty list - the original list, and not `[1,2]` - the new list.

Let's see how that works, using [id](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id):

Once declared, `GlobalDataBase` hold a reference to `a`:

```
id(GlobalDataBase.a)
Out[112]: 290675912L #Original
```

And that same reference is held by any instance we create:

```
gb1 = GlobalDataBase()
id(gb1.a)
Out[114]: 290675912L #Original
```

and after `copy_to_a`, you can see that it changed:

```
gb1.copy_to_a([1,2])
id(gb1.a)
Out[116]: 290670536L #Changed!
```

but `gb2` still has the original reference:

```
id(gb2.a)
Out[118]: 290675912L #Original
```

You said you understood the second example, but for completeness, when you do `self.a.append(value[idx])` you append to the *original* list. As said, new instances have a reference to that list, and "see" that change.

And here we can see the reference does not change:

```
gb1 = GlobalDataBase()
id(gb1.a)
Out[120]: 290675912L #Original

gb1.assign_to_a([1,2])
id(gb1.a)
Out[122]: 290675912L #Original

gb2 = GlobalDataBase()
id(gb2.a)
Out[124]: 290675912L #Original
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it's good enough for my problem. Now I understand both methods well.