# Python class instance not being destroyed at end of method

Tags: python, class, garbage-collection, ipython, spyder

I should begin by saying this is being run in IPython, using the Spyder IDE if it makes a difference. I am somewhat of a newbie at Python but fluent in other languages.

I have a class which is instantiated and used in a function, like below. I have simplified the code from a very long reading and processing algorithm. This all works fine the first time I run this file and call ReadFile(). Any subsequents runs crash, basically because m_seclist and m_headers already contain data.

My understanding of classes comes from C++, PHP and VB so I may be off with my assumptions, but as the class is instantiated within a function (ie local scope), should the instance not be completely destroyed at the end of the function? In this case it appears it very definitely isn't, or at least some of the variables are surviving. Am I misunderstanding how Python deals with class instances?

```
class Reader:
    m_headers = []
    m_seclist = []


    def __init__(self, filename):
        fh = open(filename, 'r')
        file_contents = fh.read().splitlines()
        fh.close()

        dataPointList = []

        for line in file_contents:
            for each section in the file (more code here)
                thisLine = line.split()
                dataPointList.append((float(thisLine[1]), float(thisLine[0])))
            m_seclist.append(dataPointList)
            dataPointList = []

    def getData(self, index):
        return m_seclist[index][0]

  #end of class
   def ReadFile(filename):
       my_instance = Reader(filename)
       output = my_instance.getData(2)
       return output
```

If I can clarify something, yell.

Comment: Could you clarify how you noticed that "some of the variables are surviving"?

Comment: and where is the rest of your code? I don't see any object initiation.

Comment: Essentially the ReadFile function crashes the second time it is run (ie run straight after the first time), and whilst debugging I printed the m_seclist lists to discover that they contained two copies of the data (e.g 1,2,3,1,2,3 where it should be 1,2,3)

Comment: @kasperTaeymans I think its the my_instance = Reader(filename) line, is this not the correct way to initialise a class?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/q/1680528/3001761

Comment: yes it is but your indentation is somewhat wrong... it seems that ReadFile is part of the class... but it isn't.

Comment: I interpreted it as a separate function. There is no static method decorator.

Comment: @TomKilney not quite.  What we're talking about here is Class members and Instance members.  There's a difference.  Class members are available from all instances of that particular class.  This is great for static values that are the same across all instances.  Instance members are dynamic to each instance.

Comment: @TomKilney this is consistent, not crazy - everything else you define at the same level (e.g. the methods) belong to the class, not an instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the way you store the data:

Class attributes are stored in the class and shared between all instances of a class.

Instance attributes, instead, count per instance.

Instead of

```
class Reader:
    m_headers = []
    m_seclist = []


    def __init__(self, filename):
```

do

```
class Reader:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.m_headers = []
        self.m_seclist = []
        ...
```

Then they are new and fresh in every instance.

Comment: how do you make something an instance attribute versus shared?

Comment: @TomKilney [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)?

Comment: thanks, and I will. I can't say I've come across a case where a class variable would be useful, but presumably such cases exist!

Comment: @Tom They definitely exist.

Comment: do you have an example (I'm curious)

Comment: @TomKilney For example, a list of class instances which have been created...

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood class and instance members. What you do with this:

```
class Reader:
    m_headers = []
    m_seclist = []
```

is declare class members. And they survive.

What you want is this, oh and convention in python is to just prefix with `_` private members. I've also added with statement which is preferred for handling resources that need closing.

```
class Reader:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._headers = [] # This creates instance members
        self._seclist = []
        with open(filename, 'r') as fh: # With statement will auto close fh
            file_contents = fh.read().splitlines()

        for line in file_contents:
            dataPointList = []
            for each section in the file (more code here)
                thisLine = line.split()
                dataPointList.append((float(thisLine[1]), float(thisLine[0])))
            self._seclist.append(dataPointList)

    def getData(self, index):
        return self._seclist[index][0]

def ReadFile(filename):
    my_instance = Reader(filename)
    output = my_instance.getData(2)
    return output
```

Comment: Why the `_`? I don't consider it necessary here...

Comment: I just translated his convention of private member variables `m_varname` to Python's `self._varname`