# Python class not intitializing itself to empty

Tags: python-2.7

How come the length Current_Stock.open can be greater than 0 if I just created the instance of the class?

```
def initialize_stock(row):
    Current_Stock=Stock()
    print len(Current_Stock.open)
    do some stuff than return object
```

Loop that calls initializer

```
for row in xrange(1,sheet.nrows,25):
        New_Stock= Stock() #create new instance of class
        New_Stock= initialize_stock(row)
        stocks.append(New_Stock) #add instance to stocks array
```

Stock class

```
class Stock:
    name=''
    date=[]
    open=[]
    high=[]
    low=[]
    close=[]
    percent_change_price=[]
    percent_change_volume= []
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I avoid having Python class data shared among instances?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-do-i-avoid-having-python-class-data-shared-among-instances)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, that your attributes are not instance variables, but class attributes.

You declared them on class level -- and in Python this means, that they are class attributes by default.

Only variables that are created inside methods are instance variables and also they must be *always* used with "self." prefix, e.g.:

```
 def __init__(self):
     ...
     self.open = []
     ...
```

Comment: technically, It doesn't have to be `self` but rather whatever you named the first paramter, which by convention tends to be `self`

Comment: @FuriousGeorge: Off course you are right. But it is good behavior to name it this way, since this is one of the most basic Python conventions.

Comment: Does this mean I should make another function called __init__(self)? or should I just set everything to [] at the beginning of my current initialize function?

Comment: @BadCode42 the `__init__(self)` is the class inititializer.  I really think you should read the python class tutorial (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) as you seem to not quite have a grasp on how classes work and this is a fundamental idea that you will need to incorporate throughout your code.  Better to get a grasp on it now than to propagate problems throughout your code that will be hard to fix later.