# In python how is a mutable class attribute treated

Tags: python

I am executing the following Python code :

```
class Pet :
    kind = 'dog'    # class variable shared by all instances
    tricks = []

    def __init__(self, name) :
        self.name = name # instance variable unique to each instance
    def changePet(self, newPet) :
        self.kind = newPet
    def addTricks(self, tricks) :
        self.tricks.append(tricks)

pet1 = Pet('mypet')
pet2 = Pet('yourpet')
print 'pet1 kind ::: ', pet1.kind;print 'pet2 kind ::: ', pet2.kind
print 'pet1 name ::: ', pet1.name;print 'pet2 name ::: ', pet2.name

Pet.kind = 'cat'
print 'changed Pet.kind to cat'
print 'pet1 kind ::: ', pet1.kind;print 'pet2 kind ::: ', pet2.kind

#changing pet#1 kind does not change pet#2 kind
pet1.changePet('parrot')
print 'changed pet1.kind to parrot'
print 'pet1 kind ::: ', pet1.kind;print 'pet2 kind ::: ', pet2.kind

pet1.addTricks('imitate')
pet2.addTricks('roll over')
print 'pet1 tricks ::: ', pet1.tricks;print 'pet2 tricks ::: ', pet2.tricks

print Pet.__dict__
print pet1.__dict__
print pet2.__dict__
```

The output is as per the explanation I found on internet. The output is as follows

```
pet1 kind :::  dog
pet2 kind :::  dog
pet1 name :::  mypet
pet2 name :::  yourpet
changed Pet.kind to cat
pet1 kind :::  cat
pet2 kind :::  cat
changed pet1.kind to parrot
pet1 kind :::  parrot
pet2 kind :::  cat
pet1 tricks :::  ['imitate', 'roll over']
pet2 tricks :::  ['imitate', 'roll over']
{'__module__': '__main__', 'tricks': ['imitate', 'roll over'], 'kind': 'cat', 'addTricks': <function addTricks at 0xb71fa6bc>, 'changePet': <function changePet at 0xb71fa33c>, '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0xb71fa144>}
{'kind': 'parrot', 'name': 'mypet'}
{'name': 'yourpet'}
```

Now my query is that why is a mutable class object treated differently than a non-mutable class object

Comment: They are not treated differently by Python. **You** treated them differently, by assigning in one place, but using a list method in another.

Comment: Try using `self.tricks = self.tricks + [tricks]` to see the difference.

Comment: Relevant and related: [How do I avoid having Python class data shared among instances?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1680528)

Comment: Also, looks like you're a bit confused about terminology. There're no immutable variables involded in your example (except for strings, but it's essentially irrelevant). Proper terms would be _instance_ (`name`) and _shared_ (`kind` and `tricks`) attributes. Instance attributes are unique to invividual object (instance of the class), while shared are shared among *all* instances of the class.

Comment: ok @ Martijn Pieters then how is `self.tricks += [tricks]` different from ` self.tricks = self.tricks + [tricks]`

Comment: Does this invoke list.append() @Martijn Pieter

Comment: `+=` is *augmented* assignment and gives the object the chance to update in-place; for a list object that uses `list.extend()`.

Comment: @Martijn Pieter  but `+=` also creates instance attribute `tricks` and now Pet, pet1 and pet2 all have two entry list in `tricks`

Comment: @user3282758: no, you extend the class attribute: https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/20bd97cbb8876f2c1e11; the same attribute is visible on all instances because there is no instance attribute masking it.

Comment: @user3282758: `self.tricks += [tricks]` is the same thing as `self.tricks.extend([tricks])`, because list objects implement in-place augmented assignment support (one step, where `list.__iadd__([tricks])` returns the list object itself). `self.tricks = self.tricks + [tricks]` uses straight up concatenation (one step) then assignment (another step).

Comment: @Martijn Pieter, I still did not understand completely. The `__dict__` of instance as well as class show same `tricks` in case of `+=` while in case of `self.tricks.append`, the new trick was added only to class `tricks` and the `__dict__` of instance did not show an entry for `tricks` at all

Comment: @user3282758: right, yes, the attribute is added to the instance, but it is the *same list*. I actually forgot `+=` does this; it does create an instance attribute but now the list object is shared with the class (no new list object is created).

Comment: @Martijn Pieter I really appreciate your patience. When I am printing `pet1.tricks is Pet.tricks`, this returns `True` for both `append` as well as `+=`. So why is it that in case of `append` the `__dict__` of instance does not show entry for `tricks` but in case of `+=` the `__dict__` of instance does show an entry for `tricks`

Comment: @user3282758: because `list.append()` doesn't use assignment, `+=` does use assignment. Assignment on attributes on an instance creates an instance attribute if not yet there.

Comment: @Martijn Piete, OK I think I understand it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that they treated differently. You are just performing different operations on them.

In the case of `changePet`, you are assigning the previously undefined `self.kind` to a value. Now when python tries to find `pet1.kind`, it finds it immediately. When looking up `pet2.kind`, it doesn't find it. It does, however, find find `Pet.kind` so it returns that.

In the case of `addTricks`, you are attempting to mutate `self.tricks`. Since that doesn't exist, you are instead given a reference to `Pet.tricks`. Therefore, when you call `append()` on `self.tricks`, you are effective calling `Pet.tricks.append()` and not `self.tricks.append()`.

To clear things up, this:

```
def changePet(self, newPet) :
    self.kind = newPet
def addTricks(self, tricks) :
    self.tricks.append(tricks)
```

is effectively equivalent to this:

```
def changePet(self, newPet) :
    self.kind = newPet
def addTricks(self, tricks) :
    Pet.tricks.append(tricks)
```

To demonstrate that that python is not treating mutables differently than non-mutables, we need change your methods so that they perform similar operations:

```
def changePet(self, newPet) :
    self.kind = newPet

def addTricks(self, tricks):
    # assign self.tricks to a new value where we previously only mutated it!
    # note: list(self.tricks) returns a copy
    self.tricks = list(self.tricks)
    self.tricks.append(tricks)
```

Now when we run your code again, we get the following output:

```
pet1 kind :::  dog
pet2 kind :::  dog
pet1 name :::  mypet
pet2 name :::  yourpet
changed Pet.kind to cat
pet1 kind :::  cat
pet2 kind :::  cat
changed pet1.kind to parrot
pet1 kind :::  parrot
pet2 kind :::  cat
pet1 tricks :::  ['imitate']
pet2 tricks :::  ['roll over']
{'__module__': '__main__', 'tricks': [], 'kind': 'cat', 'addTricks': <function addTricks at 0x02A33C30>, 'changePet': <function changePet at 0x02A33BF0>, '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x02A33BB0>}
{'tricks': ['imitate'], 'kind': 'parrot', 'name': 'mypet'}
{'tricks': ['roll over'], 'name': 'yourpet'}
```