# Object class information crosses over in python, why?

Tags: python, class, object

I am trying to save events for different items as they occur.  However, when I go to get the results, only 1 event's occurrences are printing and I am not sure why.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime as DT

class test:
    event = {}

    def __init__(self,pin,name):
        self.name = name
        self.pin = pin

    def somethingHappens(self,what):
        self.event[what] = DT.now()

    def printResults(self):
        sortKeys = (self.event).keys()
        sortKeys.sort()
        print self.name
        for k in sortKeys:
            value = repr(k) + "," + repr(self.event[k])
            print value

objList = []
objects = {'book':3, 'bottle':5, 'pen':8}
nameList = objects.values()
numList = objects.keys()
for i in range(len(nameList)):
    objList.append(test(nameList[i],numList[i]))

x = 0
while x <= 1:
    objList[x].somethingHappens('Start')
    time.sleep(.5)
    objList[x].somethingHappens('End')
    time.sleep(1)
    x += 1

x = 0
while x <= 2:
    objList[x].printResults()
    x += 1
```

with results:

```
pen
'End',datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 22, 9, 39, 10, 947000)
'Start',datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 22, 9, 39, 10, 432000)
book
'End',datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 22, 9, 39, 10, 947000)
'Start',datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 22, 9, 39, 10, 432000)
bottle
'End',datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 22, 9, 39, 10, 947000)
'Start',datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 22, 9, 39, 10, 432000)
```

Hopefully it is something simple.

Comment: If I print the results during the first while loop, then the results come out correctly.

Comment: `event` is a class attribute, when it should be an instance attribute.

Comment: Given that you do have instance attributes, why on earth did you make `event` a class attribute? Put `self.event = {}` into `__init__`.

Comment: I don't think that's a good duplicate; there are no default function arguments in this question.

Comment: @chepner you're right, sorry; I meant this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-do-i-avoid-having-python-class-data-shared-among-instances. Could you do the honours?