# Python classes, basic

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, python-3.x

I tried creating a Complex number class. I have an add method in the class which returns a new complex number after adding, without changing the argument complex numbers.

**code**

```
class complex:
    real = 0.00
    imag = 0.00

    def __init__ (self,r,i):
        complex.real = r
        complex.imag = i

    def add(comp1, comp2):
        x = comp1.real + comp2.real
        y = comp1.imag + comp2.imag
        result = complex(x,y)
        return result
```

Something is wrong with this code. I cannot find it. Please tell me where I went wrong.

[image]

I also tried passing self object but it didin't work. `def add(self, comp):`

Comment: First of all why are you updating class attributes? Use `self`.

Comment: This has already been asked time and time again, the problem is that you use class variables (which are shared among all instances) instead of instance variables (which are specific for each instance). I can't find the original question right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I avoid having Python class data shared among instances?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-do-i-avoid-having-python-class-data-shared-among-instances)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> class complex:
>     real = 0.00
>     imag = 0.00
>
>     def __init__ (self,r,i):
>         complex.real = r
>         complex.imag = i
> ```

1. You're using class properties which are globally the same for all instances of `complex`. You only want to assign those values to `self`, not `complex` itself.

> ```
> def add(comp1, comp2):
>     x = comp1.real + comp2.real
>     y = comp1.imag + comp2.imag
>     result = complex(x,y)
>     return result
> ```

2. You're missing the `self` parameter, or you want to make the method [a `@staticmethod`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner).

Correct implementation:

```
class Complex:
    def __init__ (self, real=0.00, imag=0.00):
        self.real = real
        self.imag = imag

    def add(self, comp):
        return Complex(self.real + comp.real, self.imag + comp.imag)


c1 = Complex(1, 2)
c2 = Complex(3, 4)
c3 = c1.add(c2)
```

Comment: Your `add` method is exactly the same as OP's one, just using a different naming. (even though I understand that using such naming, the OP understanding of a method might not be complete.)

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking that's true, but as you say, it's probably an indicator of a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

When you do -

```
complex.real = r
complex.imag = i
```

This is the reason for your issue, when you create a new instance of `complex` class, the `real` and `imag` values for the class change to the new one, and this is reflected across all instances of the complex object.

`real` and `imag` are actually class variables, that are shared accross all objects/instances of the class. You should define them as instance variables as -

```
def __init__ (self,r,i):
    self.real = r
    self.imag = i
```

`self` points to the current instance, so when you do - `self.real` it points to the `real` variable of the current instance/object.

Answer (score 1):

In your `__init__`, you should refer to `self` instead of `complex` for object / dynamic properties, otherwise you're modifying them as class / static properties:

```
def __init__ (self,r,i):
    self.real = r
    self.imag = i
```