# Modifying a class attribute from instance, different behaviour depending on type?

Tags: python, oop, object

If I create a class in Python and I give it a class attribute (this is taken directly from the docs, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)), as

```
class Dog:

    tricks = []            

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add_trick(self, trick):
        self.tricks.append(trick)
```

I see that, as the docs suggest, when doing

```
d1 = Dog('d1') 
d2 = Dog('d2') 

d1.add_trick('trick') 
print d2.tricks
```

I get that the trick is added to d2 as well:

```
['trick']
```

This is because `tricks` is a class attribute rather than an instance attribute so gets shared across all instances (correct me if this is not orthodox!).

Now, suppose I do this instead

```
class Dog:

    a = 1

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def improve_a(self):
        self.a += 1
```

and I run

```
d1 = Dog('d1') 
d2 = Dog('d2') 

d1.improve_a() 
print d1.a, d2.a
```

this gives me 2 and 1 respectively, namely the count for the second instance has not changed. Why is this, why the behaviour difference?

Comment: `self.a += 1` really executes as `self.a = self.a + 1`...

Comment: Because in one case you're mutating a mutable class attribute, shared by all instances (http://stackoverflow.com/q/1680528/3001761), in the other you're shadowing an immutable class attribute with an immutable instance attribute. They're really not the same situation. *"different behaviour depending on type"* is exactly what you **should** expect, otherwise things in OOP would be very boring indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `int` class does not define the += operator (`__iadd__` method). That wouldn't make sense because it is immutable.

That's why `+=` defaults to `+` and then `=`. [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__)

`self.a += 1` becomes `self.a = self.a + 1`

Now the first time you call `improve_a` the following happens:

1. read class attribute `a` and put it on the stack
2. add `1` to the item on the stack
3. **create a new instance attribute `a`** and assign it the value on the stack

That means the class attribute is **not changed at all** and you add a new instance attribute.

On every subsequent call of `improve` on the same object the instance attribute is incremented, because attribute lookup starts on the instance dict and will only go to the class dict if that attribute does not exist.

If you do the same with a mutable class which overloads the `__iadd__` method you can get different behaviour:

```
class HasList:
    some_list = []

    def add_something(self, value):
        some_list += [value]

fst = HasList()
sec = HasList()

fst.add_something(1)
fst.add_something(2)
sec.add_something(3)

print(HasList.some_list, fst.some_list, sec.some_list)
```

You will see that all instances and the class itself still hold the same list. The print shows the same list `[1, 2, 3]` each time. You can also check that all three lists are identical: `fst.some_list is sec.some_list and fst.some_list is HasList.some_list  # -> True`.

That is because `list.__iadd__` just calls `list.extend` and returns itself inside the method (at least if it was written in python).