# length python multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, variable-length

I have a strange error in the following code:

```
s = MyClass()
f = open(filename, 'r')
nbline = f.readline()
for line in iter(f):
        linesplit = line.split()
        s.add(linesplit)
f.close()

print(len(s.l))
print(nbline)
```

the two print don't give me the same result. Why?

the class definition is:

```
class MyClass:
    l = []
    def add(self, v):
        self.l.append(v)
```

and the file format is:

```
161
3277 4704 52456568 0 1340 380 425
3277 4704 52456578 1 1330 380 422
3118 4719 52456588 1 1340 390 415
3109 4732 52456598 1 1340 400 420
3182 4743 52456608 1 1350 410 427
3309 4789 52456618 1 1360 420 446
...
```

for this file the print are:
51020
161

and the file contain 162 line (the number of line + the line)

If I call the function one it's ok, the error appear when I call the function twice or more (it's look like previous file are read!!! :/)

Comment: What does the file look like ? Cause I am guessing the first line has the number of lines and then you just want to make sure it corresponds.

Comment: first line = nb line

Comment: after it´s: num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 num6 mum7\n

Comment: It doesn't help to put it here in the comment like this, can you please update your question with an example file? thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I avoid having Python class data shared among instances?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-do-i-avoid-having-python-class-data-shared-among-instances)

Comment: I've reverted question content to match original one. Both duplicate votes should be ignored, as they refer to different question posted as edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thanks for the edit.

Here is a better looking and more pythonic code:

```
s = MyClass()
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    nbline = f.readline()
    for line in f:
        linesplit = line.split()
        s.add(linesplit)
```

Then make sure you are setting `self.l = []` in your `MyClass`

Comment: sorry I didn't know I need to edit to now I will doing it :)

Comment: This code is in a function and when i call it the second time in another file the size is different because it contain also the older file!! :/ i don't understand i close the other file and create a new object...

Answer (score 0):

Try something the lines of:

(len(list[first dimension]) + len(list[second dimension])) etc...

A bit clunky but I think it will do what you want

Comment: So how to get le number of element in a list but without counting element in element @Hugh Evans?

Answer (score 0):

The file probably has a trailing newline or two. If `len(s.l) == nbline + 1` or  just print `s.l[-3:]` to check.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is that s.l is a class variable shared by all instances!!!