# How to instantiate a new property object for each new parent object?

Tags: python

I'm working a special situation where I'm trying to emulate the django feel of model classes like so:

```
class packet(models.packet):
    field1 = models.IntField()
    field2 = models.IntField()
```

There's a lot of background interfacing using metaclassing but the over idea is to allow the user to interact with the fields like so:

```
p = packet()
p.field1 = 12
p.field1 == 12 # true
```

while still not compromising the field type:

```
isinstance(p.field1, models.IntField) # true
```

The problem that I'm facing is that two `packet` objects share the same `Fields` since they're class properties:

```
p1 = packet()
p2 = packet()

p1.field1 = 12
p2.field2 = 14

p1 is p2 # false
p1.field1 is p2.field1 # true
```

How do I instantiate a new property object for each new parent object?

To give better context feel free to browse the [source here](https://github.com/KronoSKoderS/CalPack/blob/dev/calpack/models.py)

Comment: I've updated to the question to hopefully reflect the bigger problem that I'm facing and therefore hopefully still not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances

Comment: You're trying to have both `p.field1 == 12` *and* `isinstance(p.field1, models.IntField)`? Don't try it; you'll end up in a horrible world of non-transitive `==` and 3 dozen operator overloads and a dozen entries on your "known issues" list that will never go away.