# Instance of has no member

Tags: instance, member

Maybe I'm getting something basic confused but I cant seem to work out how to fix this issue.

[image]

The compiler gives me

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 153, in <module>
  File "python", line 90, in finish
  File "python", line 25, in registered
AttributeError: 'Marathon' object has no attribute 'runnerList'`

Which all seem to be the same issue. Surely the instance does have members. I'm not sure why it thinks it doesn't.

```
class Marathon:

# Creator
# -------

runnersList = []
timesList = []

def __init__(self):
  """Set up this marathon without any runners."""

# Inspectors
# ----------

# These are called anytime.

def registered(self, runner):
  """Return True if runner has registered, otherwise False."""
  for item in self.runnerList:
    if item == runner:
      return True
  else:
    return False
```

Comment: `runnerList` is not `runnersList`.

Comment: Also you're declaring class attributes instead of instance attributes. [You should fix that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances)