# What are the possible alternatives to making all variables in a function global in Python?

Tags: python

Okay, so I know you shouldn't /really/ make variables global - they're meant to be local. However I am programming a blackjack game and I need to reset the cards every time the user wants to play again - so I have made a function called 'reset' and it calls that if the it is going to repeat. My main question is, should I do this or is there a better method of solving my problem, or is there a better way of doing this than just typing out global _____ every time?
Here's my code if anyone wants to see;

```
import random
playagain = True
def reset():
    global cards
    global gameCards
    global playerCards
    global cpuCards
    global pgameCards
    global cpugameCards
    global start
    cards = ["A♠", "2♠", "3♠", "4♠", "5♠", "6♠", "7♠", "8♠", "9♠", "10♠", "J♠", "Q♠", "K♠",
             "A♥", "2♥", "3♥", "4♥", "5♥", "6♥", "7♥", "8♥", "9♥", "10♥", "J♥", "Q♥", "K♥",
             "A♣", "2♣", "3♣", "4♣", "5♣", "6♣", "7♣", "8♣", "9♣", "10♣", "J♣", "Q♣", "K♣",
             "A♦", "2♦", "3♦", "4♦", "5♦", "6♦", "7♦", "8♦", "9♦", "10♦", "J♦", "Q♦", "K♦"]
    gameCards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
                 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
                 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
                 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    playerCards = []
    cpuCards = []
    pgameCards = []
    cpugameCards = []
    start = 0
```

[...]

```
while playagain == True:
    reset()
    winner = game()
    print("Your cards: ", playerCards)
    print("CPU's cards: ", cpuCards)
    print(winner)
    askUser = input("Play again? Y/N ")
    if askUser.upper() == "Y":
        playagain = True
    else:
        playagain = False
```

Comment: The best way to do this is to not use global variables at all. Python makes it annoying to do this, among a few reasons, precisely to discourage you from using them.

Comment: Create a class, make these member values, and then provide a `new_game()` method that sets all of the values to their initial states.

Comment: There is most likely always a better solution not using globals.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is there any other way that would make it possible to do what I need?

Comment: @g.d.d.c I'm not too sure how to do that - I am still fairly new to python, any help?

Comment: This question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @jaco0646 sorry! kind of new to this, came via Google to find a solution and didn't find it so just asked here. thanks for letting me know for the future

Comment: @hannah, no problem. Your question is valid; there just happens to be a more appropriate venue where you'd potentially get better answers in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Global variables is a feature of python but if you want to code elegantly I believe global variables shouldn't be used at all.

I like to pass variables from function to function instead. 
My solution may not look very elegant but it actually is in my opinion.

***Note:*** I have also included the 3 print statements into the `game()` function to make it simpler since they are called no matter what the output of game is.

Here is my solution:

```
import random
playagain = True
def reset():
    cards = ["A♠", "2♠", "3♠", "4♠", "5♠", "6♠", "7♠", "8♠", "9♠", "10♠", "J♠", "Q♠", "K♠",
             "A♥", "2♥", "3♥", "4♥", "5♥", "6♥", "7♥", "8♥", "9♥", "10♥", "J♥", "Q♥", "K♥",
             "A♣", "2♣", "3♣", "4♣", "5♣", "6♣", "7♣", "8♣", "9♣", "10♣", "J♣", "Q♣", "K♣",
             "A♦", "2♦", "3♦", "4♦", "5♦", "6♦", "7♦", "8♦", "9♦", "10♦", "J♦", "Q♦", "K♦"]
    gameCards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
                 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
                 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
                 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    playerCards = []
    cpuCards = []
    pgameCards = []
    cpugameCards = []
    start = 0
    return cards, gameCards, playerCards, cpuCards, pgameCards, cpugameCards, start



def game(cards, gameCards, playerCards, cpuCards, pgameCards, cpugameCards, start):

    # [Main Code]

    winner = 'abcd' # put whatever you return from your original game() function as the value of winner 
    print("Your cards: ", playerCards)
    print("CPU's cards: ", cpuCards)
    print(winner)

while playagain == True:
    cards, gameCards, playerCards, cpuCards, pgameCards, cpugameCards, start = reset()
    game(cards, gameCards, playerCards, cpuCards, pgameCards, cpugameCards, start)
    askUser = input("Play again? Y/N ")
    if askUser.upper() == "Y":
        playagain = True
    else:
        playagain = False
```

Comment: I have used that for my main game's program - didn't know I could implement that here.

Comment: @confused yeah its a pretty nice way to have the program flow and the advantage of this is that since functions are taking input values and giving output values and each function is a system, you can reuse functions with a few modifications in other programs as well. I'm not the greatest at explaining it lol, lemme know if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks for the help! seems to be running well now

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a notch in the right direction:

```
import random

playagain = True

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # init all members
        pass

    def Reset(self):
        self.cards = ["A?", "2?", "3?", "4?", "5?", "6?", "7?", "8?", "9?", "10?", "J?", "Q?", "K?",
                 "A?", "2?", "3?", "4?", "5?", "6?", "7?", "8?", "9?", "10?", "J?", "Q?", "K?",
                 "A?", "2?", "3?", "4?", "5?", "6?", "7?", "8?", "9?", "10?", "J?", "Q?", "K?",
                 "A?", "2?", "3?", "4?", "5?", "6?", "7?", "8?", "9?", "10?", "J?", "Q?", "K?"]
        self.gameCards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
                     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
                     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
                     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
        self.playerCards = []
        self.cpuCards = []
        self.pgameCards = []
        self.cpugameCards = []
        self.start = 0
```

Here you have an Object that holds all methods the object can do. You have to read a bit about object oriented programming and learn about the way it is implemented in python.

Comment: thank you! I'm studying A-Level computer science so OOP is coming later in the course (hardly anything was covered in the old GCSE) - but I will look into it and do some reading on it, will be helpful to get a little ahead and within my current code :)

Comment: @What what are those class variables for?

Comment: @confused just to create some anticipation: all datatypes in python are objects so learning how to use methods and access variables will come handy.

Comment: [I think you probably wanted to create instance variables instead of class variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances)

Comment: If you just want anticipation, this seems like a good use of type hints: `cards: list; gameCards: list`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on [What](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5651419/what)'s answer, instead of resting all the cards in the game you could delete the current Game object and create new object. And then set all your initial states within a init function. Below is a example

```
import random

class Game:
    cards = []
    gameCards = []
    playerCards = []
    pgameCards = []
    cpugameCards = []
    start = 0
    '''+all your class attributes'''

    def __init__(self):
        '''insert your initial states here'''
        pass
```

Then to start a new game you would do something like the following:

```
'''To start a new game'''
game = Game()
```

Then to finish the current game you could do something like the following:

```
'''To end the current game'''
del game
```

If your resetting a game aren't you technically creating a new game? That's why I recommend creating and deleting game objects

Reason why you do not want to deal with global variables can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

All the best with your game!

Comment: thanks! I will bear this in mind as I look into OOP and go back to my program and modify it