# Appending an object to the list of an instance, but only in that instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of objects called `TerrainTile`.
Each of these instances have a list called `resourceList`.

```
resourceList = []
```

I append an object called `obj` to this list within this method:

```
def add_resource_object (self, obj):
    self.resourceList.append(obj)
    return
```

For some reason, instead of each individual instance having its own list called `resourceList`, it seems all instances are sharing the same `resourceList` list and when it is appended to all instances are appended to.

Why is the `.append()` appending to all instances of `TerrainTile`?

Comment: The problem is that from the start your `self.resourceList` probably all point to the same list. You need to show how your class / instances are constructed, specially `self.resouourceList`.

Comment: Blind guess: you're defining `resourceList` in your class outside of your constructor. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1680528/354577 (Side note: it would be more common to call this `resource_list` in Python code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your snippet above:

```
resourceList = []
```

You're creating a class variable shared between all instances, rather than an instance variable that's local to a particular instance. Instead, initialize your instance variable like so:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.resourceList = []
```

See here for details: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments and other answers, you are passing around the same instance variable to each list. Depending on the type of your object, you may be able to make a copy of it before adding it to each list.

Import it like this

```
from copy import deepcopy
```

Use it like this

```
new_obj = deepcopy(obj)
```