# How to copy instances of a class?

Tags: python

So far I've done programming in C, C++, and Java. Python is totally new so this problem seems kind of awkward to me. I created two instances box1 (class Rectangle) and box2 (also class Rectangle). The member p which is an instance of the class Point inside the class Rectangle seems to be shared between both instances (box1 and box2). How to make the instances completely independent?

```
import copy

class Point:
    x=0
    y=0

class Rectangle:
    width=0
    height=0
    p=Point()

box1=Rectangle()

box1.width=5
box1.height=6
box1.p.x=2
box1.p.y=3

box2=Rectangle()

print(box1 is box2)

print(box1.p is box2.p)
```

Output:

**False
True**

Comment: That's why I remembered to mention that on my first line. I'm actually reading "Think Python" by Allen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why in python you instantiate classes with the `__init__(self)` method.

If you change your code to

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
class Rectangle:
     def __init__(self):
        self.width = 0
        self.height = 0
        self.p = Point()
box1=Rectangle()

box1.width=5
box1.height=6
box1.p.x=2
box1.p.y=3

box2=Rectangle()

print(box1 is box2) # output is false

print(box1.p is box2.p) # output is false
```

Comment: Seems to be working now! Could you please tell me why we use  "def __init__(self)"?

Comment: Look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances

Comment: Just looked into that, thanks for the help :)