# Creating variable in class or in __init__ in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, initialization, member

where is a difference between creating a variable in a class and assign it a value in `__init__` and creating the variable directly in `__init__`?

For example:

**Example 1:**

```
# I create the var color outside __init__ and assigns a value to it inside __init__

class Car:
   color = ""
   def __init__(self):
      self.color = "green"
```

**Example 2:**

```
# I directly create the variable inside __init__ and not outside __init__ and just assign a value in __init__

class Car:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
```

Does it make a difference?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances

Answer (score 1):

The first example has two different `color` attributes: `color = ""` creates a *class* attribute show value will be used if the instance doesn't have its own. `self.color = "green"` explicitly creates an *instance* attribute with the value `"green"`.

In your second example, there is no class attribute, and you define the instance attribute using an argument to `__init__` rather than a hard-coded value.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is the constructor used to initiate an object when the object is created.

```
-> __init__(self): self.color='green'
```

this will create a class variable, and you won't be able to pass a new value while creating the object.

```
->__init__(self,color): self.color=color
```

On the other hand, above piece of code will allow you to assign color attribute to your object.