# are python3 mutable attributes shared?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mutable

In the code I instantiate two different objects of the same class, how is it possible that `object1` alters `object2`'s attributes? How can I keep different "self.mutable" variables? Where's my mistake? :-)

thanks

```
class Class:
    mutable = {}
    immutable = 0

    def change(self):
        self.immutable = 1
        self.mutable["key"] = "value"

    def observe(self):
        print(self.immutable, self.mutable)


object1, object2 = Class(), Class()

object1.change()
object2.observe()
# output is: 0 {'key': 'value'}
```

Comment: By the way, `self.mutable` isn't a method. `change` and `observe` are methods.

Comment: A variable that is set outside `__init__` belongs to the class and is shared by all instances.

Comment: thanks @Kasrâmvd it works!! :-D

Comment: @user2357112 I have reopened this question because there are some more nuances to it here than in the canonical dupe for class level variables. I hope you don't mind. (EAFP)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined `mutable` and `immutable` on the class level,
therefore both will be [shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances) across all instances of `Class`. The answers in the linked question explain in detail how to avoid the sharing behavior you are observing, so I will just explain what goes on with your code.

In principle, this sharing is unrelated to the attributes being mutable or immutable, but there are some nuances in your code that can make it confusing.

In the case of `mutable`, the observed behavior is pretty easy to explain.

First of all, the dict `mutable` is always the same object in memory:

```
>>> o1, o2 = Class(), Class()                                                                         
>>> o1.mutable is o2.mutable is Class.mutable                                                         
True
```

when you mutate `mutable` in any way, this change will be seen everywhere a reference to that dict is held.

```
>>> Class.mutable                                                                                     
{}
>>> o2.mutable[1] = 2                                                                                 
>>> o1.change()                                                                                       
>>> Class.mutable                                                                                     
{1: 2, 'key': 'value'}
```

So far all of this is expected. The tricky part with `immutable` is that you don't mutate `Class.immutable` in change, you *assign* the attribute `immutable` to the instance (`self`) `change` is being called on!

Before calling change, `immutable` only exists on the class level and is accessed through the class when looked up on the instance `o1` or `o2`. (Note how the instance dicts of `o1` and `o2` are empty.)

```
>>> o1, o2 = Class(), Class()                                                                         
>>> o1.immutable, o2.immutable, Class.immutable                                                       
(0, 0, 0)
>>> o1.__dict__, o2.__dict__, 'immutable' in Class.__dict__                                           
({}, {}, True)
```

When calling `change` on `o2`, you only set the attribute `immutable = 1` on the instance `o2`!

```
>>> o2.change()                                                                                       
>>> o1.immutable, o2.immutable, Class.immutable                                                       
(0, 1, 0)
>>> o1.__dict__, o2.__dict__, 'immutable' in Class.__dict__                                           
({}, {'immutable': 1}, True)
>>> o1.immutable is Class.immutable                                                                   
True
>>> o2.immutable is Class.immutable                                                                   
False
```

It's important to understand that mutable and immutable objects set at the class level are shared in exactly the same way. The only difference is that mutable objects have no methods on them that change them. But if you had done `self.mutable = {'key': 'value'}` in `change` and then called `change` on a specific instance, the `mutable` attribute defined on the instance would take precedence over the attribute defined at the class level when looking it up on the instance via the dot-notation.