# Django UpdateView initial parameter passed to other UpdateView's

Tags: django

I have two update views accessed with different urls. In the first update view `CreateType` I set a variable in my initial called `old_type`. After I submit and go through other views I end up in my second UpdateView `CreateSchedule`. if i print self.initial in my second view I find the var `old_type` I have set in my first UpdateView for some reason.

First view

```
class CreateType(views.UpdateView):
    """
    Create type form
    """
    model = Group
    form_class = TypeForm
    template_name = 'create.html'
    extra_context = {'has_fifth_steps': False, 'active_step': 1, 'progress': 0}

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        object = super(CreateType, self).get_object(queryset)
        self.initial['old_type'] = object.type
        return object

    def form_valid(self, form):
        object = form.save()
        if object.type == Group.TYPE_SINGLE and self.initial['old_type'] == Group.TYPE_MULTIPLE:
            first_obj = Obj.objects.filter(group=object).values('id').first()
            if first_obj:
                Obj.objects.filter(group=object).exclude(id=first_obj['id']).delete()
        return redirect('create_obj.debtor', pk=object.pk)
```

My second view:

```
class CreateSchedule(views.UpdateView):
    """
    Schedule form
    """
    model = Group
    fields = []
    template_name = 'createschedule.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        object = super(CreateSchedule, self).get_object(queryset)
        # if object.type == Group.TYPE_SINGLE:
        self.obj_object = Obj.objects.filter(group=object).first()
        return object

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        paymentschedule_formset = modelformset_factory(
            model=PaymentSchedule,
            form=PaymentScheduleForm,
            fields=('due_date', 'value'),
            validate_min=True,
            min_num=self.obj_object.number_of_payments,
            validate_max=True,
            max_num=self.obj_object.number_of_payments,
        )

        print(self.initial)
        return paymentschedule_formset(
            queryset=PaymentSchedule.objects.filter(obj=self.obj_object),
    )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateSchedule, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.object.type == Group.TYPE_MULTIPLE:
            context['has_fifth_steps'] = True
            context['active_step'] = 5
        else:
            context['has_fifth_steps'] = False
            context['active_step'] = 4
        context['progress'] = 100
        return context
```

Not sure if I am doing something wrong or this is a normal behavior which doesn't make much sense to me.

Appreciate any help!

Edit:

Added urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('create/<int:pk>/', sanad.CreateType.as_view(), name='create_obj.type'),
path('create/<int:pk>/payments-schedule', CreatesSchedule.as_view(), name='create_obj.schedule'),
]
```

Comment: Where are you seeing that?

Comment: In the `print(self.initial)` in get_form in the second view

Comment: Could you share how are you navigating to different views?

Comment: That definitely shouldn't be happening - even between two different invocations of the CreateType view, let alone two completely different views.

Comment: I added my urls to show the navigation. This links to next is just a submit button like so `<button type="submit">{% trans "Next" %}</button>`

Comment: One thing I have noticed which makes things more weird, is that if I change my initial statement in the first view to `self.initial = {'old_type' : object.type}` the above does not happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't ever modify `self.initial`. That is a dictionary defined at class level in the FormMixin, which is used by CreateView. If you modify that dict, that modification is visible by all views.

You shouldn't do this. Anyway, changing initial within `get_object` is the wrong thing to do. Instead, define the `get_initial()` method to return a new dictionary containing this value:

```
def get_initial(self):
    return {'old_type': self.object.type}
```

Now you shouldn't need to override `get_object` at all.

Comment: Thanks, I get your answer, may I ask how is the variable getting transferred between the views? I am trying to trace that with no avail.

Comment: And also, why is it that when I do `self.initial = {'old_type' : object.type}` instead of the above, it works as expected?

Comment: It's not getting transferred, as I said it is a class-level attribute defined in FormMixin, see https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L12.  Doing that defines a new *instance* variable, rather than modifying the class variable. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances).