# set size is changing even though it shouldn't python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, pycharm

```
class Test:
    TheFlag = True
    StartNodeQuery = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

    def parsa(self):
        while self.TheFlag:
            SNQ = self.StartNodeQuery
            self.iterator(SNQ)

    def iterator(self, CurrentNodeQuery):

        #it prints {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
        print(CurrentNodeQuery)


        if len(CurrentNodeQuery) < 100:
            b = len(CurrentNodeQuery) * 2
            c = len(CurrentNodeQuery) * 3
            self.StartNodeQuery.update({b, c})

            # it prints {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15}
            print(CurrentNodeQuery)

        else:
            self.TheFlag = False

        assert 0

obj = Test()
obj.parsa()
```

as you can see I deliberately ended the program with assert 0.
The Main issue is:
Before the function is finished the parameters that is passed to it gets changed!

as you can see 
StartNodeQuery = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and 
SNQ = self.StartNodeQuery

so why when I change the size of the self.StartNodeQuery inside the function before it's  finished , CurrentNodeQuery which is a different variable with the same values as self.StartNodeQuery (or SNQ) gets changed as well, even though we didn't pass the new self.StartNodeQuery to CurrentNodeQuery  yet?

I hope you understand my problem, if you have the solution, please help a guy out

Comment: Parameter passing doesn't copy objects. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: [Also you're making class variables instead of instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances), but that's a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues and suggestions in your code

- Don't mix class and instance variables. You are using class variables `TheFlag` and `StartNodeQuery` as instance variables, so make them one
- Use a constructor to instantiate instance variables
- Perhaps use `exit()` to break the function
- You need to explicitly copy the set to make a new instance via [copy.copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.copy). Assignment `SNQ = self.StartNodeQuery` just makes a new reference to the variable

So the fixed code might look like

```
from copy import copy

class Test:

    def __init__(self):

        # Made instance variables as class variables
        self.TheFlag = True
        self.StartNodeQuery = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

    def parsa(self):

        while self.TheFlag:
            SNQ = self.StartNodeQuery.copy()
            self.iterator(SNQ)


    def iterator(self, CurrentNodeQuery):

        #it prints {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
        print(CurrentNodeQuery)


        if len(CurrentNodeQuery) < 100:
            b = len(CurrentNodeQuery) * 2
            c = len(CurrentNodeQuery) * 3
            self.StartNodeQuery.update({b, c})

            # it prints {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15}
            print(CurrentNodeQuery)

        else:
            self.TheFlag = False

        #Use exit to break the function
        exit()

obj = Test()
obj.parsa()
```

And the output will be

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```