# Python class attribute inconsistency

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am trying to understand how class attributes work in Python. I have confusion based on following example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class Bag:
    val = 100
    items = []

    def add(self, x):
        self.items.append(x)
        print(self.items)

b1 = Bag()
b1.add('book')
b1.val += 1
print(b1.val)

b1.add('pen')
b1.val += 1
print(b1.val)

b2 = Bag()
b2.add('sketches')
b2.val += 1
print(b2.val)

b2.add('text')
b2.val += 1
print(b2.val)

b2.add('canvas')
b2.val += 1
print(b2.val)
```

Output expected:

```
['book']
101
['book', 'pen']
102
['book', 'pen', 'sketches']
103
['book', 'pen', 'sketches', 'text']
104
['book', 'pen', 'sketches', 'text', 'canvas']
105
```

Output seen:

```
['book']
101
['book', 'pen']
102
['book', 'pen', 'sketches']
101
['book', 'pen', 'sketches', 'text']
102
['book', 'pen', 'sketches', 'text', 'canvas']
103
```

Why is there inconsistency between list being shared vs different copies of integers?

Here is another example that shows a different behavior for `int`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class Person:
    cl_roll = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.roll = self.next_roll()
        print(self.roll, self.name)

    @classmethod
    def next_roll(cls):
        cls.cl_roll += 1
        return cls.cl_roll

p1 = Person('Eve')
p2 = Person('Abel')
p3 = Person('Eva')
```

Output expected based on previous output:

```
1 Eve
1 Abel
1 Eva
```

Actual output:

```
1 Eve
2 Abel
3 Eva
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid having class data shared among instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances)

Comment: Thank you, will check the link.

Comment: It is still not clear to me. Any further explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: That's not a useful problem statement, *"Any further explanation"* could mean anything. What exactly is unclear? One important thing to note: integers are *immutable*.

Comment: The link discusses dictionary related issue and does not directly address this question.

Comment: What? The duplicate also talks about a list class attribute. That said, it it *was* a dictionary, which is also a mutable container, it would still apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will extend your example a bit

```
class Bag:
   items = []
   items1 = []
   val = 100
   def add(self, x):
       self.items.append(x)
       self.val += 1
       self.items1 += [x]


b1 = Bag()
print(Bag.__dict__)
#op-1>>> 'items': [], 'items1': [], 'val': 100,
print(b1.__dict__)
#op-2>>> {}

b1.add(111)
print(Bag.__dict__)
#op-3>>> {'items': [111], 'items1': [111], 'val': 100}
print(b1.__dict__)
#op-4>>>{'items1': [111], 'val': 101}
```

To go step-by-step:

1. `self.items.append(x)`:

   First, python tries to find if we have a `items` in the `object (self.__dict__)`, if not then it tries to find `items` from the class scope and appends it. Nothing is returned as part of this expression. `self.__dict__` is untouched after this expression.
2. `self.val += 1`

   This is augmented assignment for int. So `__iadd__` will be called, if this is not implemented 's `__add__`  will be called which will always return a new int. The old int is not changed in-place because it is immutable. To elaborate

   self.val = self.val + 1

   The first time `self.val` on the `rhs` refers to the class attribute *(since b1.**dict** does not have it)* and it creates a new int which is now stored in the object's `__dict__` (because of lhs).. The second time `self.val` in the `rhs` refers to the val in `self.__dict__` Instead if you would have done `Bag.val += 1`, then it will always manipulate the class variable (like your second example)
3. `self.items1 += [x]`

So this is also augmented addition of the `list.__iadd__`. `self.items1` **is changed in-place** for mutable sequences and the reference to the same list is also returned as part of this expression. So, after this statement, you should see that `self.__dict__` will contain `items1` but with same contents as `Bag.__dict__['items1']`.

Your second example is altogether different:

```
cls.cl_roll += 1
```

this statement always manipulates the class variable.

Comment: Thank you @sam-daniel! I had to lookup magic methods but it's worth it. IMHO, it would have been better if class variables are accessed/modified only using class methods.

Answer (score 0):

The list `items` is one shared object among all the instances of your class. You *modify* it with `self.items.append(x)` but you don't ever create another list. So every reference to `.items` is working on the shared object `Bag.items`

However, when you do

```
b1.val += 1
```

This is like writing

```
b1.val = b1.val + 1
```

And because `b1` does not yet have an individual value for `val`, the effect you get is:

```
b1.val = Bag.val + 1
```

You are assigning to `b1.val` a new value that is different from `Bag.val`.

So your instances have a shared `items`, but have individual `val`, because you actually *assign* to `b1.val` etc.

Comment: Not really. I have examples to demonstrate the same. It can be reproduced this way. Create multiple objects in which only a few modify class variable. Then change class variable either using class/classmethod. Only some of them see modified values.