# Dataclass nested within another dataclass does not update data correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I generate two different instances of a python `dataclass` which includes a nested `dataclass`.  When I update a value in the nested `dataclass` in one instance (but not in the other), the same data is placed in the nested `dataclass` in *both* instances.  This is not what I expected.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class sub1:
    q: int = 10
    r: str = "qrst"


@dataclass
class A:
    a: int = 1
    s1: sub1 = sub1()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    aa = A()
    aa.a = 9
    aa.s1.r = "92"
    print("a:", repr(a))
    print("aa:", repr(aa))

''' Produces --
a: A(a=1, s1=sub1(q=10, r='92'))
aa: A(a=9, s1=sub1(q=10, r='92'))
'''
```

I expected the nested `dataclass` to be updated in only the specified instance (`aa`) and for the nested `dataclass` in the other instance (`a`) to remain unchanged.

What am I doing wrong, or is `dataclass` the wrong tool?

Comment: This has nothing to do with dataclasses, this would work the same way if you did `s1: sub1 = []` This is how default values *always work*.

Comment: Also note, this isn't "nesting". You are simply using an object as an attribute of another object, *composition* would be the jargon. Also, please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances although, perhaps the involvement of data-classes makes it worthy of it's own question, but the answer/root cause is essentially the same.

Comment: This is not a generic python question as it is python 3 that has dataclasses.

Comment: it *is a Python question* so it should be tagged with the generic tag. Use a version-specific tag at your discretion

Comment: juanpa.  I've thought about this a bit more, and you're right.  I'll be careful about this in the future.

Answer (score 12):

What you are currently doing is providing a default value for the field.  As that value is a mutable object, changes to that object will be visible to all instances of your dataclass.

What you should do instead is provide a [default factory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) that produces `sub1` instances for each new `A` instance:

```
from dataclasses import field

@dataclass
class A:
    a: int = 1
    s1: sub1 = field(default_factory=sub1)

a = A()
aa = A()
aa.a = 9
aa.s1.r = "92"
print("a:", repr(a))  # a: A(a=1, s1=sub1(q=10, r='qrst'))
print("aa:", repr(aa))  # aa: A(a=9, s1=sub1(q=10, r='92'))
```