# Access item in class list

Tags: python, class, methods, class-method

I'm trying to determine whether the first item in a tuple within a list exists in the assignments list using the following code.

```
class Students:
    id = int()
    full_name = ""
    assignments = [("Assign_1", 4), ("Assign_2", 10)]

    def __init__(self, id, full_name):
        self.id = int(id)
        self.full_name = full_name

    def get_name(self):
        print(self.full_name)
    def get_assignments(self):
        print(self.assignments)
    def get_assignment(self, name):
        if name in self.assignments:
            return name
        else:
            return None

Becky = Students(123, "Becky S")
Becky.get_assignments()
print(Becky.get_assignment("Assign_1"))
```

I've included more code than necessary just to illustrate the concept. When I use the `get_assignments()` method to return all assignments, I'm able to do so, but when I use `get_assignment` to print out the name of a single assignment, I keep returning `None`, as if the assignment doesn't exist. I think the issue is in how I'm defining `get_assignment(self, name)`, but can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not to do with classes. It is that you are trying to search for a string in a list of tuples.

`self.assignments` is `[("Assign_1", 4), ("Assign_2", 10)]`. That is, each element in the list is a tuple of (name, id). When you do `in`, Python will compare the argument with each elemnt of the list. But `"Assign_1"` will never equal `("Assign_1", 4)`.

Instead you would need to loop over the list and check if the name is in any of the elements:

```
if any(assignment[0] == name for assignment in self.assignments)
```

Note also, you have some issues with your understanding of Python classes. You don't want to define `id` or `name` at class level. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances) for more.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just check for inclusion with `in` because that string isn't an element of the list — the list has tuples. You check if [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) of the assignments have a first member that equals `name` with something like:

```
def get_assignment(self, name):
    if any(assignment[0] == name for assignment in self.assignments):
        return name
    else:
        return None
```

This will look though the assignments and compare `name` to the 0th element of each one and return `True` when it finds or `False` if it doesn't.