# Why does some solution work on VSCode but not LeetCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.7

I tried to resolve this [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-a-stack-with-increment-operation/) problem with the solution as follows on Visual Studio Code :

```
class CustomStack:
    vals = list()

    def __init__(self, maxSize):
        self.maxSize = maxSize

    def push(self, x):
        if len(self.vals) < self.maxSize:
            self.vals.append(x)
        print(self.vals)

    def pop(self):
        if len(self.vals) > 0:
            val = self.vals.pop()
            print(val)
            return val
        else:
            print(-1)
            return -1

    def increment(self, k, val):
        k = min(k, len(self.vals))
        for i in range(k):
            self.vals[i] += val
        print(self.vals)
```

It prints correct numbers on VSCode: [null,null,34,null,-1,null,null,63,null,null,null,null]

But it fails on LeetCode which prints [null,null,85,null,181,null,null,196,null,null,null,null]

I know the correct solution can be this:

```
class CustomStack:
    def __init__(self, maxSize):
        self.vals =[]
        self.maxSize = maxSize
```

But why the original version works on VSCode, not Leetcode?

Comment: `vals` in your code is a class variable, not on the instance. Leetcode is probably running multiple tests using your code. Each test will share `vals`. Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running your program in VS Code, you are testing a single example using one instance of the `CustomStack` class. In LeetCode, multiple test cases are executed using a new instance of the `CustomStack` class. Since `vars` is a class variable, not an instance variable, it is being shared across all of the `CustomStack` instances created during execution of your program. This means that each instance modifies the same `list`.

You have already shown that the correct way to implement a variable specific to an instance of a class is by defining it during the `__init__` method:

```
class CustomStack:
    def __init__(self, maxSize):
        self.vals =[]
        self.maxSize = maxSize
```