# Why does empty class instantiation in Python links the created objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, instantiation

In Python 3.8.3, I created a simple class that contains a dictionary as follows:

```
class trees:

    fruits = {}
 
    def __init__(self, initFruits = {}):
        self.fruits = initFruits

    def printFruits(self):
        for f in self.fruits:
            print(f, self.fruits[f])
```

Next, I call the class to create an empty object, and populate it

```
marigold = trees()
marigold.fruits["apple"] = 3
marigold.printFruits()
```

Printing the contents gives the expected: `apple 3`

However, I then want to create another empty object

```
riverdale = trees()
riverdate.printFruits()
```

Printing the contents gives me the same out as the Marigold object: `apple 3`

Furthermore, when I add more items into the Riverdale object, the Marigold object gets altered as well

```
riverdale.Fruits["orange"] = 5
marigold.printFruits()
```

Its contents become:

```
apple 3
orange 5
```

I wanted to create a separate object, why are they somehow linked?

Comment: The reason it happens is because when the interpreter reads through your definition of your code and comes to this row `def __init__(self, initFruits = {}):` it will then create an empty dictionary there. However it will always point to the same dictionary. Change that to `initFruits=None` and then check inside of the method for `None` and create an empty dictionary instead.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Default arguments are evaluated *once* at function definition time. Note also, your `fruits = {}` in the class body is totally pointless. It creates a *class variable* which gets shadowed by your instance variable in `__init__`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances). You should take a look at the [official tutorial / docus on python class definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations and help! I tried searching for the answer but didn't get the keywords right. Hope my question here can help direct other beginners to the previously answered posts.