# Python unittest shares object attributes between independent tests cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, shared-memory, python-unittest

I'm working on a Python project and wanted to cover my code with unit tests. For each test I create a test class with multiple methods, and define initial testing conditions inside a method. Specifically, I have a class Node which I test in Test1 class, and all tests work as expected. But then, I want to test a different segment of code. For that purpose I create new class Test2 and create an instance of Node class inside a method of Test2. When I create it I expect the object to have default attributes that initialized with `__init__()`, however it has parameters initialized in Test1. I'm not sure why the objects have shared attributes even though I do not explicitly share them.

Below is my project structure:

```
package_with_tests
|- objects
   |- __init__.py
   |- node.py
   |- time_series.py
|- tests
   |- t_objects
      |- __init__.py
      |- t_func.py
      |- t_node.py
   |- __init__.py
   |- tests_collect.py
|- __init__.py
```

Here is a `time_series.py` code

```py
import numpy as np


class TimeSeries:
    _ts = np.array([])
    _ys = np.array([])

    def __init__(self, ts: (np.ndarray, list), ys: (np.ndarray, list)):

        if isinstance(ts, list):
            ts = np.array(ts)

        if isinstance(ys, list):
            ys = np.array(ys)

        self.ts = ts
        self.ys = ys

    @property
    def ts(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return self._ts

    @ts.setter
    def ts(self, val: np.ndarray):
        self._ts = val

    @property
    def ys(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return self._ys

    @ys.setter
    def ys(self, val: np.ndarray):
        self._ys = val

    @property
    def size(self) -> int:
        return self._ts.shape[0]

    def append(self, ts, ys):
        self._ts = np.append(self._ts, ts)
        self._ys = np.append(self._ys, ys)
```

`node.py` code:

```py
from package_with_tests.objects.time_series import TimeSeries


class Node:
    _attribute_1 = TimeSeries([], [])
    _rt_attribute = (0, 0)

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def attribute_1(self) -> TimeSeries:
        return self._attribute_1

    @attribute_1.setter
    def attribute_1(self, val: TimeSeries):
        self._attribute_1 = val

    @property
    def rt_attribute(self) -> tuple:
        return self._rt_attribute

    @rt_attribute.setter
    def rt_attribute(self, val: tuple):
        self._rt_attribute = val

        ts, ys = val

        self._attribute_1.append(ts, ys)
```

`tests.t_objects.t_node.py` code

```py
from unittest import TestCase

from package_with_tests.objects.node import Node


class Test1(TestCase):
    def test_1_1(self):
        node = Node()

        self.assertEqual(node.attribute_1.size, 0)

        # Note that I append new value to time_series if rt_attribute get updated
        node.rt_attribute = (10, 20)
        self.assertEqual(node.attribute_1.size, 1)
        self.assertEqual(node.attribute_1.ts[0], 10)
```

`tests.t_objects.t_func.py` code:

```py
from unittest import TestCase

from package_with_tests.objects.node import Node


class Test2(TestCase):
    def test_2_1(self):
        # Here I create a new Node object and I would expect it to come with 
        # default attributes, i.e. 
        #    _attribute_1 = TimeSeries([], [])
        #    _rt_attribute = (0, 0)
        # But, get attribute_1 defined in Test1.test_1_1()
        node404 = Node()

        self.assertEqual(node404.attribute_1.size, 0,
                         msg=f"size={node404.attribute_1.size}, "
                             f"ts={node404.attribute_1.ts}, "
                             f"ys={node404.attribute_1.ys}")
```

And code of `tests_collect.py`

```py
import unittest

from package_with_tests.tests.t_objects.t_node import Test1
from package_with_tests.tests.t_objects.t_func import Test2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()

    test_suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(Test1))
    test_suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(Test2))

    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(test_suite)
```

I run all the tests with command

```sh
$ python -m package_with_tests.tests.tests_collect
```

(Python version is 3.7.6) and get the following output

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_2_1 (package_with_tests.tests.t_objects.t_func.Test2)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Projects/TestProject/package_with_tests/tests/t_objects/t_func.py", line 11, in test_2_1
    msg=f"size={node404.attribute_1.size}, "
AssertionError: 1 != 0 : size=1, ts=[10.], ys=[20.]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

As you can see from row `AssertionError: 1 != 0 : size=1, ts=[10.], ys=[20.]` `node.attribute_1` has `ts` equal to `[10.]` and `ys` equal to `[20.]` that were defined in `Test1.test_1_1()`.

However if I switch the order of how tests added to the test suite in the `tests_collect.py`

```py
    ...
    test_suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(Test2))
    test_suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(Test1))
    ...
```

all tests pass without failures.

I do not understand why the object initialized in `Test2` has attributes of the object initialized in `Test1`. They get shared somehow, but I wasn't able to find an answer as of why this is happening. I tried to delete object after the test is done with

```py
del node
```

with no success.

I searched through SO and found a very similar question ([Why does the second test method appear to share the context of the first test method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630925/why-does-the-second-test-method-appear-to-share-the-context-of-the-first-test-me)) however there are no answers yet.
Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances) answer indeed helped. After I added explicit initialization of all attributes to `Node.__init__()` the issue has gone.