# I have an issue understanding Python Classes

Tags: python

I have the following class:

```
import random as rd

class Human():
    def __init__(self,name,testList=[]):

        self.name = name
        self.testList = testList

    def fill_list(self):

        self.testList.append(rd.choices([0,1],weights= [0.75,0.25],k=10))
```

and a corresponding main file that initiates two instances of the class and puts them in a list:

```
from testtest import Human

foo = Human("Bar")
faa = Human("Bor")


check = []
check.append(foo)
check.append(faa)


for entry in check:
    entry.fill_list()

for entry in check:
    print(entry.name,entry.testList)
```

when I run the main file I get the following output:

```
Bar: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Bor: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Two questions:

1. Why do both instances have the exact same list even-though they are randomly generated?
2. At what point does it call the method twice per instance?

Thanks a lot for your feedback in advance!

Comment: It is at first hard to understand. But if you declare a variable inside a class. The variable is a class member and not an instance member! That is why the default-value [] for testList is not valid, since there is already a value present for testList. You need to make sure in __init__ that a new instance of the variable is being created.
``` lang-python
class Human():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.test_list = []

    def fill_list(self):
        self.test_list.append(rd.choices([0,1],weights=[0.75,0.25],k=10))
```

Comment: @Miller That explanation is also pretty hard to understand…‽

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback! Didn't realise you could comment when the answer was already closed.
Damn I had no idea variables become class members.
The issue is in my practical case, that I need the option of instancing the testList. Is there anyway around that?

Comment: You did read the duplicate…? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416002/476

Comment: Yes but unfortunately the penny didn't drop for me while reading it. :(

Comment: Do not use `def func(arg=[])`. Instead, use `def func(arg=None)` and then `if arg is None: arg = []` in the function body.