# List in class object not working, or more-accurately working wierdly

Tags: python, list, class

I got really confused over functionality of lists working with classes.

```py
class BasicClass:
    def __init__(self,money = [200]):
        self.money=money
    def add_money(self,value):
        self.money.append(value)
object=BasicClass()
object_2=BasicClass()
object.add_money(500)
object_2.add_money(300)
print(object.money)
print(object_2.money)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[200, 500, 300]
[200, 500, 300]
```

Version with class variable:

```py
class BasicClass:
    money = [200]
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def add_money(self,value):
        self.money.append(value)
object=BasicClass()
object_2=BasicClass()
object.add_money(500)
object_2.add_money(300)
print(object.money)
print(object_2.money)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[200, 500, 300]
[200, 500, 300]
```

Version with no default

```py
class BasicClass:
    def __init__(self,money):
        self.money=money
    def add_money(self,value):
        self.money.append(value)
object=BasicClass([100])
object_2=BasicClass([100])
object.add_money(500)
object_2.add_money(300)
print(object.money)
print(object_2.money)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[100, 500]
[100, 300]
```

It looks like when I don't define my list through `__init__` when I'm creating an object, python uses the same instance of list for both objects later. I'm just wondering what is goal of this functionality and how exactly it works.

Comment: The default value is the same list.

Comment: Have a look here, it explains a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances