# Why does my class attribute (a list) keep growing each time I run it?

Tags: python, class, jupyter-notebook

```
class Seq:
    values = []

    def add(self, value):
        Seq.values.append(value)
```

I did the below in second cell of my Jupyter notebook

```
model = Seq()
model.add(1)
model.add(2)
model.add(3)

print(model.values)
```

I got this list printed out which is normal

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

But when I run the second cell again, the list keeps growing

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Run it again...

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

What am I not doing right?

Comment: `Seq.values` is a class attribute, it's shared by all instances.

Comment: You need to add the line: `Seq.values = []` somewhere. (Or `Seq.values.clear()`)

Comment: @Barmar but I created only one instance "model", the class attribute (list) keeps growing each time I call it on the instance which I don't want

Comment: How are you "running the second cell again"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid having class data shared among instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances)

Comment: @StephenAnyanwu you created a second instance when you ran the cell a second time, because the first line of the cell is `model = Seq()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Seq().values` is persistent. No matter how many instances of `Seq()` you make, there is only one instance of `values`. This is because `values` is not tied to an instances of the class. It is tied to the class in general. I guess an analogy could be: if you had a `Lung` class with a class variable of `air`. You would be referring to all the air, the ONE air that we all breathe. No matter how many `Lung` instances you make they are all referring to the same ONE air. However if you had a `self.air` you would be referring only to the air in that lung.

You just need to make `values` related to the class instance, instead of the overall class. It also might be helpful to allow `add` to accept more than one value.

```
class Seq:
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = []

    def add(self, *values):
        self.values += values

CELL_EXECUTIONS = 100
for _ in range(CELL_EXECUTIONS):       
    model = Seq()
    model.add(1)
    model.add(2)
    model.add(3, 4, 5, 6)

print(model.values) #[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: I think this is actually related to what persists between cells in Jupyter.

Comment: @Barmar - could you explain how what I did would affect that, because I do not use Jupyter. I want to give the proper answer. I don't need a dissertation - a butt-simple explanation will more than suffice.

Comment: @Barmar I suspect Jupyter isn't any different in this respect from (say) pasting the "second cell" code into a REPL, executing it, then pasting again and executing again. That would give the same behaviour that OP shows in the question. For example: https://ideone.com/dF0Wn9

Comment: So, my answer is simply over-engineered but otherwise fine?

Comment: I don't use Jupyter either, so I don't know what the issues are. From what I've seen, some things are supposed to restart afresh, the OP seems to think they're doing that.

Comment: @Barmar - I will leave as-is for now, and adjust if the OP has issues. If something about my answer is wrong, I will have more data regarding exactly what that is when the OP complains.

Comment: @Barmar broadly, things only restart afresh when you explicitly choose to restart the kernel. Otherwise, when you run a cell, it starts with whatever the globals were after the last cell execution, so there's no guarantee that the code in a cell is idempotent.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy your answer appears to work fine, I'll go with it. Thanks

Comment: @StephenAnyanwu - care to select it (big check mark) so I didn't spend my time on this for nothing?