# List is doubled only if run from console and initialized on field declaration

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test that asserts at the end the length of 2 fields (list) of object under test.
The test is green if run from IntelliJ (either test class or test method).

```
class TestExtractLegsAndPhase:

    @staticmethod
    def extract_tsv() -> str:
        path: str = (os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
                     + "/resources/FPFaultHistory.zip")
        print("extracting from " + path)
        return extract_tsv_from_zip(path)

    tsv: str = extract_tsv()

    def test_extract_leg_and_phase(self):
        # test object
        to: FhdbTsvDecoder = FhdbTsvDecoder(self.tsv)

        legs_and_phase: list[tuple[datetime, int, int]] = to.legs_and_phase
        assert len(legs_and_phase) == 4926

        # TODO for some reason this fails if run from console, but not from IDE
        session_ends: list[datetime] = to.session_ends
        assert len(session_ends) == 57

        session_starts: list[datetime] = to.session_starts
        assert len(session_starts) == 57
```

If I run in console the last 2 assertions fail, the length is 114 instead of 57. If I look at the lists: they are just doubled - all values are added at the end again. This is the test result:

```
>       assert len(session_ends) == 57
E       AssertionError: assert 114 == 57
E        +  where 114 = len([Timestamp('2023-01-26 07:42:07'), Timestamp('2023-01-26 09:48:13'), Timestamp('2023-01-30 06:28:52'), Timestamp('2023-01-30 06:42:21'), Timestamp('2023-01-30 06:45:27'), Timestamp('2023-01-30 09:48:19'), ...])

tests\unit\gems\extract_fhdb\test_fhdb_tsv_decode.py:32: AssertionError
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
found 57 sessions
found 4926 rows
```

As you see I added a print where I count the "sessions" and I see this *only once* with the correct number 57. Thus the method is only called once?
The assert for `legs_and_phase` is green everywhere.

I also know why this one is green - at least I know what to change. Here is the actual code:
that creates the lists:

```
def __extract_leg_and_phase(self) -> None:
    # extract leg and phase from given tsv with pandas
    df: DataFrame = pandas.read_csv(StringIO(self.tsv), sep='\t', header=None,
                                    converters={4: lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, FHD_TIME_FORMAT)},
                                    skiprows=0)
    # loop over all rows and extract leg and phase
    self.legs_and_phase = []
    iterator = df.iterrows()
    count = 0
    count_rows = 0
    for index, row in iterator:
        count_rows += 1
        # extract 4 (date),5 (flight leg), 6 (flight phase) from the object
        list.append(self.legs_and_phase , (row[4], row[5], row[6]))
        if row[1] == row[2] == row[3] == row[5] == row[6] == 0:
            # session end detected, next line is session start
            count += 1
            self.session_ends.append(row[4])
            self.session_starts.append(next(iterator)[1][4])
    print("found " + str(count) + " sessions")
    print("found " + str(count_rows) + " rows")
    #self.legs_and_phase = result
```

As you see I initialize `legs_and_phase` within this method while I initialize `sessions_end`, `session_starts` on field declaration.
So fixing this is not the problem:

```
    self.session_starts = []
    self.session_ends = []
```

fixes the problem.

Why does this makes a difference, only if run in console or at all? How prevent this in future? Is it bad practice to initialize fields on declaration?

**Update**

i was not able to create a minumum example - that reproduces the fail in console. but here is the complete class under test:

```
from datetime import datetime
from io import StringIO

import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame

FHD_TIME_FORMAT = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'


class FhdbTsvDecoder:


    tsv: str

    legs_and_phase: list[tuple[datetime, int, int]]

    session_starts: list[datetime] = [] # makes test fail for session starts

    session_ends: list[datetime]

    def __init__(self, tsv: str):
        self.tsv = tsv
        self.__extract_leg_and_phase()

    def __extract_leg_and_phase(self) -> None:
        # extract leg and phase from given tsv with pandas
        df: DataFrame = pandas.read_csv(StringIO(self.tsv), sep='\t', header=None,
                                        converters={4: lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, FHD_TIME_FORMAT)},
                                        skiprows=0)
        #  if we initialize the list on field declaration, tests will fail if ran from console - lists are doubled
        self.legs_and_phase = []
        # self.session_starts = [] initialzing here will fix
        self.session_ends = []
        # loop over all rows and extract leg and phase
        iterator = df.iterrows()
        for index, row in iterator:
            # extract 4 (date),5 (flight leg), 6 (flight phase) from the object
            list.append(self.legs_and_phase, (row[4], row[5], row[6]))
            if row[1] == row[2] == row[3] == row[5] == row[6] == 0:
                # session end detected, next line is session start
                self.session_ends.append(row[4])
                self.session_starts.append(next(iterator)[1][4])
```

**2nd Update**

One other hint: the problem is that one integration runs before and this one calls code that also creates an instance of FhdbTsvDecoder.
In fact both are initialized with the same data.

If i disable this integration test the problem is also solved. So for some reason both instances seem to share their fields - making the fields somehow static. Why? is there a way to get really new fields by calling the constructor?

Comment: Please give a [mre]. Best guess is something to do with https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761

Comment: If the method does not initialize `session_ends` and `session_starts`, then calling it more than once will simply accumulate more items in those lists.

Comment: but as the log say - it is called only once. the only call is from inside the class (marked as private by __) - creating a minimal example....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
session_starts: list[datetime] = []
```

This default `[]` value is evaluated when the class is and is then (accidentally) shared by all instances.
Your `__init__` function should make sure to default-initialize *all* instances.

Comment: yes - i just noticed and fixed my init- , but what does accidentally mean? because it i was not able to create a minimum example - by just creating 2 instances of an object - the fields were not shared? can you provide a minimal example - or a link?

Comment: explanation i found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances (there you see i am new to python)